# Confusion about setting something.prototype.__proto__

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code for the Express module for Node.js I came across this line, setting inheritance for the server:

```
Server.prototype.__proto__ = connect.HTTPServer.prototype;
```

I'm not sure what this does - the MDC docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited#prototype_and_**proto**) seem to say that I could just do:

```
Server.prototype = connect.HTTPServer.prototype;
```

Indeed, I did this test:

```
var parent = function(){}
parent.prototype = {
    test: function(){console.log('test')};
}

var child1 = function(){};
child1.prototype = parent.prototype;
var instance1 = new child1();
instance1.test();     // 'test'

var child2 = function(){};
child2.prototype.__proto__ = parent.prototype;
var instance2 = new child2();
instance2.test();     // 'test'
```

Looks to be the same? So yah, I'm wondering what setting object.prototype.__proto is for. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_proto\_\_ VS. prototype in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the diagram on [this page](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm) (mckoss.com) that shows the `prototype`, `constructor`, `__proto__` relations for a small hierarchy. Also the code below the diagram describes the relation quite well.

When you have a function `Base`, and set the prototype of the function object defined, the statement `Derived.prototype = new Base;` sets the `__proto__` (actually the internal `[[prototype]]`) of `Derived.prototype` to `Base.prototype` automatically, making Derived itself a class that you can instantiate objects from. This seems the be a more standards compliant way of defining a derived class.

From what I read, `__proto__` is a non-standard way of accessing the internal `[[prototype]]` of an object. It seems to be well supported, but I am not sure if it should be trusted.

In any case, your example `Server.prototype.__proto__ = connect.HTTPServer.prototype;` seems to do the derivation the other way around: first define an object, `Server` by defining the constructor and the proto, and then hook up the internal `[[prototype]]` manually to morph it into a class derived from `HTTPServer`.

As for your suggested alternative, `Server.prototype = connect.HTTPServer.prototype;`: that is a bad idea. Here, you are setting the prototype of `Server` to be the same object as the prototype of `HTTPServer`. So any changes you make to `Server` class will be directly reflected in `HTTPServer`, and will be accessible from other derived classes of `HTTPServer`. You can imageine the chaos if two classes derived from `HTTPServer` try to define the same member.

Comment: Thanks for the mckoss article link - just one clarification before we wrap up, I think I have this correct: my suggested alternative (Derived.prototype = Base.prototype) is fine if nobody screws with the prototype, the reason why we want to do "Derived.prototype = new Base" (which will set the prototype of Derived to a new object that has its [[prototype]] set to Base.prototype), is to make damned sure that any modifications to Derived's prototype CANNOT affect Base's prototype.

Comment: Your understanding and mine are the same. Since I am not very well-versed in Javascript, there may be some other subtleties I've missed, though. Also, if you need to instantiate the derived class, `Derived.prototype.constructor` will be `Base.prototype.constructor`, so it will call the wrong function if you use `new Derived`. I think.

Answer (score 2):

The non-standard property `__proto__` lets you set the prototype of an *existing* object.

In your example, both version will achieve the same effect, but there is a difference:

`child1`'s prototype is the same as `parent`'s prototype, whereas `child2`'s prototype is an empty object and this empty object's prototype is the same as `parent`'s prototype.

Of course as `child2` and its prototype don't have a method `test`, this method will be looked up further up in the prototype chain.

Also consider this:

You want to create only one object that should inherit from another object. Now, you could write a constructor function, but JavaScript has object literal notation to create objects directly and you want to use it.

If you have a constructor function, letting the new objects inherit from another object is as easy a setting the `prototype` of the constructor function to that object.

Obviously this does not work for object literals. But in Firefox you can use `__proto__` to set it:

```
var server = {
    __proto__: connect.HTTPServer.prototype,
    other: properties
};
```

---

As this property is not standard, you should avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks Felix, your's + Dysaster's answers combined really clarified things, wish I could mark both of them

Comment: Actually, __proto__ is in the ECMAScript 6 standard, it's also very well supported across modern browsers (IE9+)