# Node.js - inheriting from EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I see this pattern in quite a few Node.js libraries:

```
Master.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

(source [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster/blob/master/lib/master.js))

Can someone please explain to me with an example, why this is such a common pattern and when it's handy?

Comment: Refer to this question for info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398487/confusion-about-setting-something-prototype-proto

Comment: Note `__proto__` is an anti-pattern, please use `Master.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);`

Comment: Actually, use ```util.inherits(Master, EventEmitter);```

Comment: @Raynos What's an anti-pattern?

Comment: This is now easier with ES6 Class constructors. Check compat here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ . Check the docs or my answer below.

Comment: @Breedly is right. Use of `util.inherits` has been discouraged by the docs and the recommended way is using ES6 classes. `util.inherits` has flaws: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4179

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As the comment above that code says, it will make `Master` inherit from `EventEmitter.prototype`, so you can use instances of that 'class' to emit and listen to events.

For example you could now do:

```
masterInstance = new Master();

masterInstance.on('an_event', function () {
  console.log('an event has happened');
});

// trigger the event
masterInstance.emit('an_event');
```

**Update**: as many users pointed out, the 'standard' way of doing that in Node would be to use 'util.inherits':

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
util.inherits(Master, EventEmitter);
```

**2nd Update**: with ES6 classes upon us, it is recommended to extend the `EventEmitter` class now:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});

myEmitter.emit('event');
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events

Comment: (just a little reminder to do `require('events').EventEmitter` first-- I always forget.  Here's the link to the docs in case anyone else needs it: http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter)

Comment: BTW, the convention for instances is to lowercase the first letter, so `MasterInstance` should be `masterInstance`.

Comment: And how do you retain ability to check if: masterInstance instanceof Master?

Comment: @jayarjo it works by default, you don't have to do anything special

Comment: If you export constructor from the module, like: "module.exports = Master;" and then create an instance of it, then "masterInstance instanceof Master" will fail (not sure if it's expected?)

Comment: Nope it won't, maybe you're just doing something wrong.

Comment: `util.inherits` does a nasty thing of injecting the `super_` property into the `Master` object. It's unnecessary and tries to treat prototypical inheritance like classic inheritance. Take a look at the bottom of [this](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) page for explanation.

Comment: @Killah so, that said, which is the alternative?

Comment: @loretoparisi just `Master.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype;`. No need for supers. You can also use ES6 extends (and it's encouraged in Node.js docs on `util.inherits`) like this `class Master extends EventEmitter` - you get classical `super()`, but without injecting anything into `Master`.

Comment: As alluded to below, this is discouraged now according to [this](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)

Comment: Since `MyEmitter` in `class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}` is not adding anything to `EventEmitter` - couldn't you just `const myEmitter = new EventEmitter()` instead?

Answer (score 91):

## ES6 Style Class Inheritance

The Node docs now [recommend](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events) using class inheritence to make your own event emitter:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  // Add any custom methods here
}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', () => {
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});
myEmitter.emit('event');
```

**Note:** If you define a `constructor()` function in `MyEmitter`, you should call [`super()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) from it to ensure the parent class's constructor is called too, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: These comments are not correct and end up being misleading in this case. Calling `super()` is **not required**, as long as you don't need/define a constructor, hence Breedly's original answer (see EDIT history) was entirely correct. In this case you can copy and paste this very same example in the repl, remove the constructor entirely and it will work the same way. That is perfectly valid syntax.

Answer (score 41):

To inherit from another Javascript object, Node.js's EventEmitter in particular but really any object in general, you need to do two things:

- provide a constructor for your object, which completely initializes the object; in the case that you're inheriting from some other object, you probably want to delegate some of this initialization work to the super constructor.
- provide a prototype object that will be used as the `[[proto]]` for objects created from your constructor; in the case that you're inheriting from some other object, you probably want to use an instance of the other object as your prototype.

This is more complicated in Javascript than it might seem in other languages because

- Javascript separates object behavior into "constructor" and "prototype". These concepts are meant to be used together, but can be used separately.
- Javascript is a very malleable language and people use it differently and there is no single true definition of what "inheritance" means.
- In many cases, you can get away with doing a subset of what's correct, and you'll find tons of examples to follow (including some other answers to this SO question) that seem to work fine for your case.

For the specific case of Node.js's EventEmitter, here's what works:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

// Define the constructor for your derived "class"
function Master(arg1, arg2) {
   // call the super constructor to initialize `this`
   EventEmitter.call(this);
   // your own initialization of `this` follows here
};

// Declare that your class should use EventEmitter as its prototype.
// This is roughly equivalent to: Master.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype)
util.inherits(Master, EventEmitter);
```

Possible foibles:

- If you use set the prototype for your subclass (Master.prototype), with or without using `util.inherits`, but don't call the super constructor (`EventEmitter`) for instances of your class, they won't be properly initialized.
- If you call the super constructor but don't set the prototype, EventEmitter methods won't work on your object
- You might try to use an initialized instance of the superclass (`new EventEmitter`) as `Master.prototype` instead of having the subclass constructor `Master` call the super constructor `EventEmitter`; depending on the behavior of the superclass constructor that might seem like it's working fine for a while, but is not the same thing (and won't work for EventEmitter).
- You might try to use the super prototype directly (`Master.prototype = EventEmitter.prototype`) instead of adding an additional layer of object via Object.create; this might seem like it's working fine until someone monkeypatches your object `Master` and has inadvertently also monkeypatched `EventEmitter` and all its other descendants. Each "class" should have its own prototype.

Again: to inherit from EventEmitter (or really any existing object "class"), you want to define a constructor that chains to the super constructor and provides a prototype that is derived from the super prototype.

Answer (score 19):

This is how prototypical (prototypal?) inheritance is done in JavaScript. 
From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto):

> Refers to the prototype of the object, which may be an object or null
>   (which usually means the object is Object.prototype, which has no
>   prototype).  It is sometimes used to implement prototype-inheritance
>   based property lookup.

This works as well:

```
var Emitter = function(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

// DON'T Emitter.prototype = new require('events').EventEmitter();
Emitter.prototype = Object.create(require('events').EventEmitter.prototype);
```

[Understanding JavaScript OOP](http://robotlolita.me/2011/10/09/understanding-javascript-oop.html) is one of the best articles I read lately on OOP in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: `Y.prototype = new X();` is an anti-pattern, please use `Y.prototype = Object.create(X.prototype);`

Comment: This is good to know. Can I read up more somewhere? Would be interested how the resulting objects are different.

Comment: `new X()` instantiate an instance of `X.prototype` and initializes it by invoke `X` on it. `Object.create(X.prototype)` just instantiates an instance. You don't wnat `Emitter.prototype` to be initialized. I can't find a good article that explains this.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for pointing it out. Still trying to get into good habits on Node. The browsers are just not there for ECMA5 (and as I understood the shim is not the most reliable).

Comment: The shim is 99% reliable. Browsers are there for ECMA5. The only major ECMA5 feature that doesnt work in IE<9 is getter/setters. The rest is shimmable or you dont care about it

Comment: Cool, I think I will give it a more thorough try then.

Comment: When i do inheritance like how u said, i loose all existing properties i had on derived class. I also loose all properties of the base class which were not on the prototype of the base class. This i what i am doing: Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype). To solve the issue I am creating a json of properies I am loosing and passing them in as the second argument to Object.create. Is that correct?

Comment: You will use var Derived = Object.create(Base). Check out the inheritance library I created: http://daffl.github.com/uberproto/

Comment: The other link is also broken. Try this one: http://robotlolita.github.io/2011/10/09/understanding-javascript-oop.html

Answer (score 5):

I thought this approach from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2187-Extending-EventEmitter-To-Create-An-Evented-Cache-In-Node-js.htm was pretty neat:

```
function EventedObject(){

  // Super constructor
  EventEmitter.call( this );

  return( this );

}
```

Douglas Crockford has some interesting inheritence patterns too: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

I find inheritence is less often needed in JavaScript and Node.js.  But in writing an app where inheritence might affect scalability, I would consider performance weighed against maintainability.  Otherwise, I would only base my decision on which patterns lead to better overall designs, are more maintainable, and less error-prone.

Test different patterns out in jsPerf, using Google Chrome (V8) to get a rough comparison.  V8 is the JavaScript engine used by both Node.js and Chrome.

Here're some jsPerfs to get you started:

http://jsperf.com/prototypes-vs-functions/4

http://jsperf.com/inheritance-proto-vs-object-create

http://jsperf.com/inheritance-perf

Comment: I've tried this approach and both `emit` and `on` are coming up as undefined.

Comment: Isn't the return(this); just for chaining?

Answer (score 2):

To add to wprl's response. He missed the "prototype" part:

```js
function EventedObject(){

   // Super constructor
   EventEmitter.call(this);

   return this;

}
EventObject.prototype = new EventEmitter(); //<-- you're missing this part
```

Comment: Actually, you should use Object.create instead of new otherwise you get instance state as well as behaviour on the prototype as explained [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/2670182).  But better to use ES6 and transpile or `util.inherits` since a lot of smart people will keep those options up to date for you.