# Mixin EventEmitter methods using __proto__

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

Given an arbitrary object, I want to make it an EventEmitter:

```
var obj = {}
// mixin eventemitter
obj.on('event', ...)
obj.emit('event')
```

Also, when I type in obj, I don't want it to show the EventEmitter methods as methods. ex via CLI:

```
> obj
{}
```

Thus, right now I'm doing:

```
function mixinEventEmitter(obj) {
  obj.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype
  return obj
}
```

But people say using `__proto__` is an anti-pattern: [Node.js - inheriting from EventEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898399/node-js-inheriting-from-eventemitter)

Am I doing it correctly? Do you have a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to use [util.inherits](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) (the linked documentation contains an example that's almost exactly what you want).

Comment: but i'm not using a constructor

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `__proto__` isn't that you're using prototypes instead of constructors.  The issue is that it's the wrong way to use prototypes.  But you don't want a prototype.  You want a mixin.  Using `__proto__` is a hack that avoids doing the work of creating a mixin.  If you want a mixin, you have to do it manually, without prototypes.

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
    obj = {};

function emitter(obj) {
    // copy EventEmitter prototype to obj, but make properties
    // non-enumerable
    for (var prop in EventEmitter.prototype) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: EventEmitter.prototype[prop]
        });
    }

    // also, make sure the following properties are hidden
    // before the constructor adds them
    ["domain", "_events", "_maxListeners"].forEach(function(prop) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, {
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: undefined
        });
    });

    // call EventEmitter constructor on obj
    EventEmitter.call(obj);

    // return the obj, which should now function as EventEmitter
    return obj;
}

emitter(obj);
obj.on("event", console.log.bind(console));
obj.emit("event", "foo");
```

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3922 on why using generic objects as EventEmitters can be problematic.