# Prototyping Array to inherit from EventEmitter in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, prototype, eventemitter

Am currently working on a project where I require to inherit from **EventEmitter**. I need an array to emit events on certain cases, say, when some length has been exceeded.

I used this snippet:

```
var events = require('events');
Array.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

It works fine, but it is said it is **anti-pattern**.

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898399/node-js-inheriting-from-eventemitter), it is suggested to use:

```
util.inherits(Array, events.EventEmitter.prototype);
```

But it does **NOT** work. So what is the **right** way to do this?

Comment: Don't mess with the native `Array`. Just build a wrapper around it!

Comment: How would you build a wrapper around Array and EventEmitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that this will change all Arrays in your application and not only one. In this situation it would be better to use a new Type that extends from EventEmitter and delegates to an Array.

i.e.

```
// Create a new object that ...
function MyEventArray() {
    // ...owns an Array as property...
    this.array = new Array();
}

// ... and extends from EventEmitter...
MyEventArray.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
MyEventArray.prototype.constructor = MyEventArray;

// ... and has functions that delegate to the array.
MyEventArray.prototype.push(obj) {
    this.array.push(obj);
}
...


// This object is an EventEmitter and can be used like an Array:
var myArray = new MyEventArray();
myArray.push(someStuff);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to follow that up with a sample code on how to do that 

Comment: I have added an example. There is even an design-principle that says something like "delegaton is better then inheritence". I don't always agree with that, however I think it is much better then multiple inheritence as you would have it here.

Comment: Will I have to write methods like push and map that delegate to the Array? Isn't that tiring?

Comment: Yes, that is why I don't always agree with that principle ;-). But this seems to be the best option to me, since there is no multiple inheritance and changing the parent-prototype of Array would apply globally (change all Arrays).

Comment: This solved my problem although it requires time-to-time update for method delegations. I accept this answer. :-)