# Node: extend EventEmitter to non-prototype object

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I see this all the time:

```
Parrot.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
```

With this, each time you construct a new parrot, it can squawk.

However, supposing I construct an object with functions and don't intend to create multiple instances:

```
var parrot = {
  squawk: function(whatYouSaid){
    this.emit("SQUAWK!!!!", whatYouSaid);
  }
}
```

How would I make this extend `EventEmitter`? I tried this, and it didn't work:

```
_.extend(parrot, (new EventEmitter()));
```

Comment: I there a reason why you are not using native `util.inherits`?

Comment: @razvan AFAIK, `util.inherits` only works on constructors.

Comment: Duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898399/node-js-inheriting-from-eventemitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898399/node-js-inheriting-from-eventemitter)

Comment: Razvan, you didn't even read the question. It's not a duplicate. Sigh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend/assign `EventEmitter.prototype` to your object:

```
_.assign(parrot, EventEmitter.prototype);
```

Answer (score -1):

`util.inherits` is the native api for doing inheritance in NodeJS.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
  util = require('util');

function Parrot(){
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  ...
}

util.inherits(Parrot, EventEmitter);

var parrot = new Parrot();

parrot.on('SQUAWK!!!!', whatYouSaid);

parrot.emit('SQUAWK!!!!', 'I said this!');
```

I made a demo of different ways of doing inheritance: https://github.com/razvanz/nodejs-inheritance-demo.

Comment: But this isn't what the OP was asking.

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time to answer this, but it seems like you didn't fully read my question.