# __proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

> This figure again shows that every object has a prototype. Constructor
> function Foo also has its own `__proto__` which is Function.prototype,
> and which in turn also references via its `__proto__` property again to
> the Object.prototype. Thus, repeat, Foo.prototype is just an explicit
> property of Foo which refers to the prototype of b and c objects.

```
var b = new Foo(20);
var c = new Foo(30);
```

What are the differences between `__proto__` and `prototype`?

[image]

The figure was taken from [dmitrysoshnikov.com](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/).

*Note:  there is now [a 2nd edition (2017)](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/) to the above 2010 article.*

Comment: See also [How does `__proto__` differ from `constructor.prototype`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/650764/1048572)

Comment: I think top-down or bottom-up is a matter of preference. I actually prefer it this way, so I can trace down the diagram until I find where something comes from.

Comment: I like how JavaScript uses prototypical inheritance to resolve y.constructor to y.__proto__.constructor. I also like how Object.prototype sits at the top of the prototypical inheritance chain with Object.prototype.__proto__ set to null. I also like how the diagram makes a three column conceptual visualization of how the programmer thinks of objects as 1. instances, 2. constructors, 3. prototypes which constructors associate with those instances when instantiated via the new keyword.

Comment: Diagram makes immediate sense after you watch something like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JJgSbuj5VI , btw

Comment: And now, as I've read through the answers, feel obliged to **really** recommend the above video, as it indeed has a crystal clean (and non-WTFy) explanation of what's going on :)

Answer (score 975, accepted):

`__proto__` is the actual object that is used in the lookup chain to resolve methods, etc.  `prototype` is the object that is used to build `__proto__` when you create an object with `new`:

```
( new Foo ).__proto__ === Foo.prototype
( new Foo ).prototype === undefined
```

Comment: Ah! So `prototype` is not available on the instances themselves (or other objects), but only on the constructor functions.

Comment: @rvighne: `prototype` is only available on functions since they are derived from `Function`, `Function`, and `Object` but in anything else it is not. However, `__proto__` is available everywhere.

Comment: So `__proto__` is the actual object that is saved and used as the prototype while `Myconstructure.prototype` is just a blueprint for  `__proto__` which,  is infact the actual object saved and used as the protoype. Hence `myobject.prototype` wouldnt be a property of the actual object because its just a temporary thing used by the constructor function to outline what  `myobject.__proto__` should look like.

Comment: Probably one of those things build into the language when it was trying to imitate classical oop. If it wasn't we would perhaps instead have seen something more along the lines of `var  mycar = Object.Createfrom(car.__proto__);`  when creating objects. More true to a prototypical style of programming.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the `__proto__` property of an object is a pointer to the object's constructor function's `prototype` property? i.e. foo.__proto__ === foo.constructor.prototype

Comment: @Alex_Nabu Not quite. `newCar.__proto__` *IS* `Car.prototype`, not an instance of `Car.prototype`. While `Car.protoype` *IS* an instance of an `object`. `Car.prototype` is not something that gives `newCar` any properties or structure, it simply *IS* the next `object` in `newCar`'s prototype chain. `Car.prototype` is not a temporary `object`. It is the `object` that is set as the value of the `__proto__` property of any new `object`s made using `Car` as a `constructor`. If you want to think of anything as a blueprint `object`, think of `Car` as a blueprint for new car-`object`s.

Comment: Why can't I change, for example, `__proto__` of a string to an array instance: `s = "foo"; a = []; s.__proto__ = a;` ?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer -- Primitives in JS are a special case.  Whenever you access them they're effectively converted into an instance of the appropriate class type and then the ops are run on that.  So after the code you wrote, `s.__proto__` is something close to `(new String(s)).__proto__`.  If you replaced your first statement with `s = new String('foo')`, it'd work.  It's just this weird quirk in JS

Comment: @Niko Bellic Gotcha! It's fair to say that __proto__ property of an object is a pointer to the object's constructor function's prototype property, but that's not fully right (at least if you replace the prototype of a non native constructor by a primitive value literal _i.e: '' || 0 || true_ afaik)! 

I tested this on Chrome and it returned something different:
`function MyConstructor () {}` `MyConstructor.prototype = '';` `(new MyConstructor).__proto__ !== MyConstructor.prototype`. 

I think the browser fails to create __proto__ with a primitive literal, creating it with Object.prototype

Comment: @Niko Bellic Actually it doesn't create it with Object.prototype either, I may need to look at this for a little long, to give a more precise answer! However `(new MyConstructor).__proto__` is actually the same as `(new MyConstructor).constructor.prototype`!

Comment: @Daniel - There are so many ways to break JavaScript, but honestly I don't see the point in discussing edge cases that no sane person would ever hit!  :)

Answer (score 446):

`prototype` is a property of a Function object. It is the prototype of objects constructed by that function.

`__proto__` is an internal property of an object, pointing to its prototype. Current standards provide an equivalent `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` method, though the de facto standard `__proto__` is quicker.

You can find `instanceof` relationships by comparing a function's `prototype` to an object's `__proto__` chain, and you can break these relationships by changing `prototype`.

```js
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var myPoint = new Point();

// the following are all true
console.log(myPoint.__proto__ == Point.prototype);
console.log(myPoint.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype);
console.log(myPoint instanceof Point);
console.log(myPoint instanceof Object);
```

Here `Point` is a constructor function, it builds an object (data structure) procedurally. `myPoint` is an object constructed by `Point()` so `Point.prototype` gets saved to `myPoint.__proto__` at that time.

Comment: Also if you change the `__proto__` property of an object, it changes the object on which prototype lookups are done. For instance, you can add an object of methods as a function's `__proto__` to have a sort of callable instance object.

Comment: myPoint.__proto__.constructor.prototype == Point.prototype

Comment: @kzh lol that gave me funny result `console.log(obj1.call) // [Function: call]` 
`obj1.call()` // TypeError: obj1.call is not a function. I did `obj.__proto__ = Function.__proto__`

Comment: `myFn.__proto__ = {foo: 'bar'}`

Comment: I think I've got your Point.

Comment: `.__proto__` is now standard; although it is not always available (e.g. for `Object.create(null)`), and can be (partially) disabled even for regular objects (`delete Object.prototype.__proto__;`)

Answer (score 162):

`prototype` property is created when a function is declared.

For instance:

```
 function Person(dob){
    this.dob = dob
 };
```

`Person.prototype` property is created internally once you declare above function.
Many properties can be added to the `Person.prototype` which are shared by `Person` instances created using `new Person()`.

```
// adds a new method age to the Person.prototype Object.
Person.prototype.age = function(){return date-dob};
```

It is worth noting that `Person.prototype` is an `Object` literal by default (it can be changed as required).

Every instance created using `new Person()` has a `__proto__` property which points to the `Person.prototype`. This is the chain that is used to traverse to find a property of a particular object.

```
var person1 = new Person(somedate);
var person2 = new Person(somedate);
```

creates 2 instances of `Person`, these 2 objects can call `age` method of `Person.prototype` as `person1.age`, `person2.age`.

In the above picture from your question, you can see that `Foo` is a `Function Object` and therefore it has a `__proto__` link to the `Function.prototype` which in turn is an instance of `Object` and has a `__proto__` link to `Object.prototype`. The proto link ends here with `__proto__` in the `Object.prototype` pointing to `null`.

Any object can have access to all the properties in its proto chain as linked by `__proto__` , thus forming the basis for prototypal inheritance.

`__proto__` is not a standard way of accessing the prototype chain, the standard but similar approach is to use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`.

Below code for `instanceof` operator gives a better understanding:

object `instanceof` Class operator returns `true` when an object is an instance of a Class, more specifically if `Class.prototype` is found in the proto chain of that object then the object is an instance of that Class.

```
function instanceOf(Func){
  var obj = this;
  while(obj !== null){
    if(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Func.prototype)
      return true;
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  return false;
}
```

The above method can be called as: `instanceOf.call(object, Class)` which return true if object is instance of Class.

Comment: I was wondering why was the `prototype` object created internally in the first place? Could one simply assign static methods to the function object itself. e.g. `function f(a){this.a = a}; f.increment = function(){return ++this.a}`? Why wasn't this way chosen over adding the methods to `prototype` object? This will work if `f.__proto__ = g` where g is the base class.

Comment: Maybe `prototype` object was choosen for sharing because only the exclusive function constructor properties can be stored in function constructor object.

Comment: Actually, that would be a mess because `instanceof` would result in `({}) instanceof Function === true` as there would be no way to differentiate between prototypes if the `prototype` property is removed.

Comment: @abhisekp What do you mean by this: "This will work if f.__proto__ = g where g is the base class." I don't know if this has some meaning i don't understand, but if you were to add the properties and methods in that way, then when you used the `new` keyword to create an instance, the properties and methods wouldn't be copied over.

Answer (score 112):

To explain let us create a function

```
 function a (name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
```

When JavaScript executes this code, it adds `prototype` property to `a`, `prototype` property is an object with two properties to it:

1. `constructor`
2. `__proto__`

So when we do

`a.prototype` it returns

```
     constructor: a  // function definition
    __proto__: Object
```

Now as you can see `constructor` is nothing but the function `a` itself
and `__proto__` points to the root level `Object` of JavaScript.

Let us see what happens when we use `a` function with `new` key word.

```
var b = new a ('JavaScript');
```

When JavaScript executes this code it does 4 things:

1. It creates a new object, an empty object // {}
2. It creates `__proto__` on `b` and makes it point to `a.prototype` so `b.__proto__ === a.prototype`
3. It executes `a.prototype.constructor` (which is definition of function `a` ) with the newly created object (created in step#1) as its context (this), hence the `name` property passed as 'JavaScript' (which is added to `this`) gets added to newly created object.
4. It returns newly created object in (created in step#1) so var `b` gets assigned to newly created object.

Now if we add `a.prototype.car = "BMW"` and do 
`b.car`, the output "BMW" appears.

this is because when JavaScript executed this code it searched for `car` property on `b`, it did not find then JavaScript used `b.__proto__` (which was made to point to 'a.prototype' in step#2) and finds `car` property so return "BMW".

Comment: 1. `constructor` does not return `a()`! It returns `a`.  2. `__proto__` returns `Object.prototype`, not the root object in Javascript.

Answer (score 84):

A nice way to think of it is...

`prototype` is used by `constructor` functions. It should've really been called something like, `"prototypeToInstall"`, since that's what it is.

and `__proto__` is that "installed prototype" on an object (that was created/installed upon the object from said `constructor()` function)

Comment: I upvoted it, but maybe the downvote reason was because the statement "prototype is used by constructor() functions" might sound as if non constructor functions does not have, which is not the case, however besides that it is not our focus now also one can note that every function is potentially a constructor if called with new...

Comment: Please change "`constructor()` functions" to "constructor functions", since there might be confusion with "`__proto__.constructor()` functions".
I consider this important, as \_\_proto\_\_.constructor isn't actually invoked when a `new` keyword is used.

Comment: The statement that "_prototype is used by constructor() functions_" tells only part of an important fact but told it in a way that likely lead readers to think it is the whole fact. **prototype** is internally created for upon every function declaration in Javascript, regardless of how that function will be called in the future - with or without the **new** keyword; **prototype** of a declared function points to an object literal.

Answer (score 69):

## Prototype, [[[Prototype]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots), and __proto__

#### prototype

When you create a function, a property of type Object called *prototype* is automatically created for you (you didn't create it yourself) and is attached to the function's object (the `constructor`).

```
// Creating a new function named "Foo"
function Foo () {
  this.name = 'John Doe';
}

/* Foo has an object property called "prototype"
   The prototype was created automatically when we declared the function Foo. */
Foo.hasOwnProperty('prototype'); // true

// Once created, we can assign properties and methods to it
Foo.prototype.myName = function () {
  return 'My name is ' + this.name;
}
```

**Note**: This new *prototype* object also points to, or has an *internal-private link* to, the native JavaScript Object.

---

##### [[Prototype]]

**Now**, if you create a new object out of `Foo` using the `new` keyword, you are basically creating (among other things) a new object that has an **internal** or **private link** to the function `Foo`'s prototype we saw before:

```
const newFoo = new Foo();

newFoo.[[Prototype]] === Foo.prototype  // true
```

The **private linkage** to that function's object is called *double brackets prototype* or just `[[Prototype]]`.

---

##### __proto__

As this link is internal (therefore private), many browsers are providing us with a **public** linkage to it, named `__proto__` (also called *Double Underscore Prototype* or just *Dunder Proto* in short).

Under the hood, `__proto__` is actually a [getter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that is part of to the native JavaScript Object. It returns the internal-private prototype linkage of whatever the `this` binding is (returns the `[[Prototype]]` of `newFoo` in our case):

```
newFoo.__proto__ === Foo.prototype // true
```

---

It is worth noting that starting of `ECMAScript5`, you can also use the [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) method to get the internal private linkage:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(newFoo) === newFoo.__proto__ // true
```

---

**NOTE**
This answer doesn't intend to cover the whole process of creating new objects or new constructors but to help better understand what is `prototype`, `[[Prototype]]`, and `__proto__`, and how they work.

Comment: @Taurus, click on the header, it leads to the ECMAScript specifications doc. Check out section 9 (Ordinary and Exotic Objects Behaviours) which explain it in much more details.

Answer (score 41):

To make it a little bit clear in addition to above great answers:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name
 }; 

var eve = new Person("Eve");

eve.__proto__ == Person.prototype //true

eve.prototype  //undefined
```

*Instances* have **__proto__**, *classes* have **prototype**.

Comment: Constructor functions and classes also have a `__proto__` property, it's not reserved for instances. Constructor functions and classes have a `__proto__` property and also a `prototype` property. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002749/1347953

Comment: Short and sweet

Answer (score 20):

In JavaScript, a function can be used as a constructor. That means we can create objects out of them using the new keyword. Every constructor function comes with a built-in object chained with them. This built-in object is called a prototype. **`Instances of a constructor function use __proto__ to access the prototype property of its constructor function.`**

[image: prototype diagram]

1. First we created a constructor: `function Foo(){}`. To be clear, Foo is just another function. But we can create an object from it with the new keyword. That's why we call it the constructor function
2. Every function has a unique property which is called the prototype property. So, Constructor function `Foo` has a prototype property which points to its prototype, which is `Foo.prototype` (see image).
3. Constructor functions are themselves a function which is an instance of a system constructor called the [[Function]] constructor. So we can say that `function Foo` is constructed by a [[Function]] constructor. So, `__proto__` of our `Foo function` will point to the prototype of its constructor, which is `Function.prototype`.
4. `Function.prototype` is itself is nothing but an object which is constructed from another system constructor called `[[Object]]`. So, `[[Object]]` is the constructor of `Function.prototype`. So, we can say `Function.prototype` is an instance of `[[Object]]`. So `__proto__` of `Function.prototype` points to `Object.prototype`.
5. `Object.prototype` is the last man standing in the prototype chain. I mean it has not been constructed. It's already there in the system. So its `__proto__` points to `null`.
6. Now we come to instances of `Foo`. When we create an instance using `new Foo()`, it creates a new object which is an instance of `Foo`. That means `Foo` is the constructor of these instances. Here we created two instances (x and y). `__proto__` of x and y thus points to `Foo.prototype`.

Comment: Just to be clear: instances do no have .prototype property? Only the constructor function right? ... So a difference between an instance and its constructor function is: constructor functions have both 1. __proto__ 2. .prototype object while the instances only have .__proto__ property... correct?

Comment: @Shaz you are right. instances uses their __proto__ to access the prototype property of their constructor function.

Comment: But why why is it when you write: var car = Object.create(Vehicle); you will get car.__proto__ = Vehicle BUT you also get a car.prototype property that points to Vehicle.prototype ?

Comment: @shaz can you provide a jsfiddle so that i can visualize the situation?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shahyan3/b5tr3zhk/6/ Here it is... check out the car and car2 as examples. Any ideas?

Comment: here car.prototype is an inherited property. car inherits 'prototype' property from vehicle function. so car.prototype === vehicle.prototype.  " prototype" property is a property on vehicle. car can access it through its prototype chain. I hope this will clear your confusion

Comment: OH I see. New to JavaScript world, your answer is so good. Quickly, is it a common practice to write: Object.create(Vehicle) OR  Object.create(Vehicle.prototype)... I am guessing the latter is more popular use case - in your experience?

Answer (score 18):

I think you need to know the difference between **__proto__** , **[[prototype]]** and **prototype**.

The accepted answer is helpful, but it might imply (imperfectly) that `__proto__` is something **only relevant to objects created using `new`** on a constructor function, which is not true.

To be more precise: **`__proto__` exists on EVERY object**.

- But what is `__proto__` at all?

  - Well, it is an object referencing **another object which is also a property of all objects, called `[[prototype]]`**.
  - It's worth mentioning that `[[prototype]]` is something that JavaScript handles internally and is **inaccessible to the developer**.
- Why would we need a reference object to the property `[[prototype]]` (of all objects)?

  - Because JavaScript doesn't want to allow getting / setting the `[[prototype]]` directly, so it allows it through a middle layer which is `__proto__`. So you can think of `__proto__` as a getter/setter of the `[[prototype]]` property.
- What is `prototype` then?

  - It is something **specific to functions**(Initially defined in `Function`, i.e, `Function.prototype` and then prototypically inherited by ***newly*** created functions, and then again those functions give it to their children, forming a chain of prototypical inheritance).
  - JavaScript uses a parent function's `prototype` to set its child functions' `[[prototype]]` when that parent function is run with `new` (remember we said **all** objects have `[[prototype]]`? well, functions are objects too, so they have `[[prototype]]` as well). So when the `[[prototype]]` of a function(child) is set to the `prototype` of another function(parent), you will have this in the end:

    ```js
    let child = new Parent();
    child.__proto__ === Parent.prototype // --> true.
    ```

    (Remember `child.[[prototype]]` is inaccessible, so we checked it using `__proto__`.)

---

***Notice 1:*** Whenever a property is not in the child, its `__proto__` will be searched "implicitly". So for instance, if `child.myprop` returns a value, you can't say whether "myprop" was a property of the child, or of one of its parents' prototypes. This also means that you never need to do something like: `child.__proto__.__proto__.myprop` on your own, just `child.myprop` will do that for you automatically.

***Notice 2:*** Even if the parent's prototype has items in it, the child's own `prototype` will be an empty object initially. You can add items to it or remove from it manually though, if you want to further extend the inhertance chain(add child[ren] to the child). Or it can be manipulated implicitly, e.g., using the [class syntax](https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_7RhGr+474h).)

***Notice 3:*** In case you need to set/get the `[[prototype]]` yourself, using `__proto__` is a bit [outdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) and modern JavaScript suggests using `Object.setPrototypeOf` and `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.

Comment: If we create a function, it does not have `__proto__` property as in this snippet `function Foo() {}; Foo.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')`

So would it be correct to say, "__proto__ exists on EVERY object" ?

Answer (score 11):

[image: JavaScript prototype vs __prototype__]

```
'use strict'
function A() {}
var a = new A();
class B extends A {}
var b = new B();
console.log('====='); // =====
console.log(B.__proto__ === A); // true
console.log(B.prototype.__proto__ === A.prototype); // true
console.log(b.__proto__ === B.prototype); // true
console.log(a.__proto__ === A.prototype); // true
console.log(A.__proto__ === Function.__proto__); // true
console.log(Object.__proto__ === Function.__proto__); // true
console.log(Object.prototype === Function.__proto__.__proto__); // true
console.log(Object.prototype.__proto__ === null); // true
```

In JavaScript, Every object(function is object too!) has a `__proto__` property, the property is reference to its prototype.

When we use the `new` operator with a constructor to create a new object,
the new object's `__proto__` property will be set with constructor's `prototype` property,
then the constructor will be call by the new object,
in that process "this" will be a reference to the new object in the constructor scope, finally return the new object.

Constructor's prototype is `__proto__` property, Constructor's `prototype` property is work with the `new` operator.

Constructor must be a function, but function not always is constructor even if it has `prototype` property.

Prototype chain actually is object's `__proto__` property to reference its prototype,
and the prototype's `__proto__` property to reference the prototype's prototype, and so on,
until to reference Object's prototype's `__proto__` property which is reference to null.

For example:

```
console.log(a.constructor === A); // true
// "a" don't have constructor,
// so it reference to A.prototype by its ``__proto__`` property,
// and found constructor is reference to A
```

`[[Prototype]]` and `__proto__` property actually is same thing.

We can use Object's getPrototypeOf method to get something's prototype.

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === a.__proto__); // true
```

Any function we written can be use to create an object with the `new` operator,
so anyone of those functions can be a constructor.

Answer (score 10):

### Summary:

The `__proto__` property of an object is a property that maps to the `prototype` of the constructor function of the object. In other words:

`instance.__proto__ === constructor.prototype // true`

This is used to form the `prototype` chain of an object. The `prototype` chain is a lookup mechanism for properties on an object. If an object's property is accessed, JavaScript will first look on the object itself. If the property isn't found there, it will climb all the way up to `protochain` until it is found (or not)

### Example:

```js
function Person (name, city) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.age = 25;

const willem = new Person('Willem');

console.log(willem.__proto__ === Person.prototype); // the __proto__ property on the instance refers to the prototype of the constructor

console.log(willem.age); // 25 doesn't find it at willem object but is present at prototype
console.log(willem.__proto__.age); // now we are directly accessing the prototype of the Person function
```

Our first log results to `true`, this is because as mentioned the `__proto__` property of the instance created by the constructor refers to the `prototype` property of the constructor. Remember, in JavaScript, functions are also Objects. Objects can have properties, and a default property of any function is one property named prototype.

Then, when this function is utilized as a constructor function, the object instantiated from it will receive a property called `__proto__`. And this `__proto__` property refers to the `prototype` property of the constructor function (which by default every function has).

### Why is this useful?

JavaScript has a mechanism when looking up properties on `Objects` which is called **'prototypal inheritance'**, here is what it basically does:

- First, it's checked if the property is located on the Object itself. If so, this property is returned.
- If the property is not located on the object itself, it will 'climb up the protochain'. It basically looks at the object referred to by the `__proto__` property. There, it checks if the property is available on the object referred to by `__proto__`.
- If the property isn't located on the `__proto__` object, it will climb up the `__proto__` chain, all the way up to `Object` object.
- If it cannot find the property anywhere on the object and its `prototype` chain, it will return `undefined`.

For example:

```js
function Person (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

let mySelf = new Person('Willem');

console.log(mySelf.__proto__ === Person.prototype);

console.log(mySelf.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
```

Answer (score 8):

I happen to be learning prototype from [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md), which is a wonderful book to understand the design underneath and clarify so many misconceptions (that's why I'm trying to avoid using inheritance and things like `instanceof`).

But I have the same question as people asked here. Several answers are really helpful and enlightening. I'd also love to share my understandings.

---

#### What is a prototype?

Objects in JavaScript have an internal property, denoted in the specification as`[[Prototype]]`, which is simply a reference to another object. Almost all objects are given a non-`null`value for this property, at the time of their creation.

#### How to get an object's prototype?

via `__proto__`or `Object.getPrototypeOf`

```
var a = { name: "wendi" };
a.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === Object.prototype // true

function Foo() {};
var b = new Foo();
b.__proto__ === Foo.prototype
b.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype
```

#### What is the `prototype` ?

`prototype` is an object automatically created as a special property of a **function**, which is used to establish the delegation (inheritance) chain, aka prototype chain.

When we create a function `a`, `prototype` is automatically created as a special property on `a` and saves the function code on as the `constructor` on `prototype`.

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype // Object {constructor: function}
Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo // true
```

I'd love to consider this property as the place to store the properties (including methods) of a function object. That's also the reason why utility functions in JS are defined like `Array.prototype.forEach()` , `Function.prototype.bind()`, `Object.prototype.toString().`

Why to emphasize the property of a **function**?

```
{}.prototype // undefined;
(function(){}).prototype // Object {constructor: function}

// The example above shows object does not have the prototype property.
// But we have Object.prototype, which implies an interesting fact that
typeof Object === "function"
var obj = new Object();
```

So, `Arary`, `Function`, `Object`are all functions. I should admit that this refreshes my impression on JS. I know functions are first-class citizen in JS but it seems that it is built on functions.

#### What's the difference between `__proto__` and `prototype`?

`__proto__`a reference works on every **object** to refer to its `[[Prototype]]`property.

`prototype` is an object automatically created as a special property of a **function**, which is used to store the properties (including methods) of a function object.

With these two, we could mentally map out the prototype chain. Like this picture illustrates:

[image]

```
function Foo() {}
var b = new Foo();

b.__proto__ === Foo.prototype // true
Foo.__proto__ === Function.prototype // true
Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
```

Answer (score 8):

Consider below code :

```js
let Letter= function() {}
    
let a= new Letter();
let b= new Letter();
let z= new Letter();

// output in console
a.__proto__ === Letter.prototype;                  // true
b.__proto__ === Letter.prototype;                  // true    
z.__proto__ === Letter.prototype;                  // true
Letter.__proto__ === Function.prototype;           // true
Function.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype; // true
Letter.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype;   // true
```

We can depict the above code in the following figure :

[image: Prototype vs proto vs prototype]

Now let's explore `[[Prototype]]`, `__proto__` and `prototype` in details :

### `[[Prototype]]`

`[[Prototype]]` is an internal hidden property of objects in JS and it is a reference to another object. Every object at the time of creation receives an object (or null) as `[[Prototype]]`. When we reference a property on an object `[[Get]]` operation is invoked like, `myObject.a`. If the object itself has a property, `a` on it then that property will be used.

```js
let myObject = {
  a: 2,
};

console.log(myObject.a); // 2
```

But if the object itself directly does not have the requested property then `[[Get]]` operation will proceed to follow the `[[Prototype]]` link of the object. This process will continue until either a matching property name is found or the `[[Prototype]]` chain ends (at the built-in `Object.prototype`). If no matching property is found then `undefined` will be returned. Now `Object.create(anyObject)` creates an object with the `[[Prototype]]` linkage to the specified `anyObject`.

```js
let anotherObject = {
  a: 2,
};

// create an object linked to anotherObject
let myObject = Object.create(anotherObject);
console.log(myObject.a); // 2
```

Both `for..in` loop and `in` operator use `[[Prototype]]` chain lookup process. So if we use `for..in` loop to iterate over the properties of an object then all the enumerable properties which can be reached via that object's `[[Prototype]]` chain will also be enumerated along with the enumerable properties of the object itself. And when using `in` operator to test for the existence of a property on an object then `in` operator will check all the properties via `[[Prototype]]` linkage of the object regardless of their enumerability.

```js
// for..in loop uses [[Prototype]] chain lookup process
let anotherObject = {
  a: 2,
};

let myObject = Object.create(anotherObject);

for (let k in myObject) {
  console.log("found: " + k); // found: a
}

// in operator uses [[Prototype]] chain lookup process
console.log("a" in myObject); // true
```

### `__proto__`

`__proto__` is a property of objects in JS and it references the another object in the `[[Prototype]]` chain. We know `[[Prototype]]` is an internal hidden property of objects in JS and it references another object in the `[[Prototype]]` chain. We can get or set the object referred by the internal `[[Prototype]]` property in 2 ways

1. `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) / Object.setPrototypeOf(obj)`
2. `obj.__proto__`

We can traverse the `[[Prototype]]` chain using:  `.__proto__.__proto__. .` . Along with `.constructor`, `.toString()`, `.isPrototypeOf()`. The dunder proto property (`__proto__`) actually exists in the built-in `Object.prototype` root object, but available on any particular object. `__proto__` is actually a getter/setter. Implementation of `__proto__` in `Object.prototype` is as follows :

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "__proto__", {
  get: function () {
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
  },
  set: function (o) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, o);
    return o;
  },
});
```

To retrieve the value of `obj.__proto__` is like calling, `obj.__proto__()` which actually returns the calling of the getter fn, `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` which exists on `Object.prototype` object. Although `__proto__` is a settable property but we should not change `[[Prototype]]` of an already existing object because of performance issues.

Using `new` operator if we create objects from a function then internal hidden `[[Prototype]]` property of those newly created objects will point to the object referenced by the `prototype` property of the original function.  Using `__proto__` property we can access the other object referenced by internal hidden `[[Prototype]]` property of the object. But `__proto__` is not the same as `[[Prototype]]` rather a getter/setter for it.

### `prototype`

`prototype` is a property of functions in JS and it refers to an object having constructor property which stores all the properties (and methods) of the function object.

```js
let foo = function () {};

console.log(foo.prototype);
// returns {constructor: f} object which now contains all the
// default properties

foo.id = "Walter White";

foo.job = "teacher";

console.log(foo.prototype);
// returns {constructor: f} object which now contains all the
// default properties and 2 more properties that we added to
// the fn object
/*
    {constructor: f}
        constructor: f()
            id: "Walter White"
            job: "teacher"
            arguments: null
            caller: null
            length: 0
            name: "foo"
            prototype: {constructor: f}
            __proto__: f()
            [[FunctionLocation]]: VM789:1
            [[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
        __proto__: Object
    
*/
```

But normal objects in JS does not have `prototype` property. We know `Object.prototype` is the root object of all the objects in JS. So clearly `Object` is a function i.e. `typeof Object === "function"` . That means we also can create an object from the `Object` function like, `let myObj= new Object()`. Similarly `Array`, `Function` are also functions so we can use `Array.prototype`, `Function.prototype` to store all the generic properties of arrays and functions. It means we can say JS is built on functions.

```js
{}.prototype;                            // SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    
(function(){}).prototype;                // {constructor: f}
```

Also using `new` operator if we create objects from a function then internal hidden `[[Prototype]]` property of those newly created objects will point to the object referenced by the `prototype` property of the original function. In the below code, we have created an object, `obj` from a fn, `Letter` and added 2 properties one to the fn object and another to the prototype object of the fn. Now if we try to access both of the properties on the newly created object, `obj` then we only will be able to access the property added to the prototype object of the function. This is because the prototype object of the function is now on the `[[Prototype]]` chain of the newly created object, `obj`.

```js
let Letter = function () {};

let obj = new Letter();

Letter.from = "Albuquerque";
Letter.prototype.to = "New Hampshire";

console.log(obj.from); // undefined
console.log(obj.to); // New Hampshire
```

Comment: Thank you, I ve read a lot of post... and yours is the most convincing one. It is hard to digest in the beginning, but then everything has sense.

Comment: "*Every object at the time of creation receives a non-null value for [[Prototype]].*" - uh, no? The [[prototype]] may be `null` as well, such as for `Object.prototype` or `Object.create(null)`. It's `null` where the lookup chain ends, not at the builtin `Object.prototype` object.

Answer (score 7):

I know, I am late but let me try to simplify it.

Let us say there is a function

```
    function Foo(message){

         this.message = message ; 
     };

     console.log(Foo.prototype);
```

Foo function will have a prototype object linked. So,Whenever we create a function in JavaScript, it always has a prototype object linked to it.

Now let us go ahead and create two objects using the function Foo.

```
    var a = new Foo("a");
    var b = new Foo("b");
    console.log(a.message);
    console.log(b.message);
```

1. Now we have two objects, object a and object b. Both are created
   using constructor Foo. Keep in mind constructor is just a word here.
2. Object a and b both have a copy of message property.
3. These two objects a and b are linked to prototype object of constructor Foo.
4. On objects a and b, we can access Foo prototype using __proto__ property in all browsers and in IE we can use Object.getPrototypeOf(a) or Object.getPrototypeOf(b)

Now, Foo.prototype, a.__proto__, and b.__proto__  all denotes same object.

```
    b.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(a);
    a.__proto__ ===  Foo.prototype;
    a.constructor.prototype  === a.__proto__;
```

all of above would return true.

As we know, in JavaScript properties can be added dynamically. We can add property to object

```
    Foo.prototype.Greet = function(){

         console.log(this.message);
    }
    a.Greet();//a
    b.Greet();//b
    a.constructor.prototype.Greet();//undefined
```

As you see we added Greet() method in Foo.prototype but it is accessible in a and b or any other object which is constructed using Foo.

While executing a.Greet(), JavaScript will first search Greet in object a on property list. On not finding , it will go up in __proto__ chain of a. Since a.__proto__ and Foo.prototype is same object, JavaScript will find Greet() method and execute it.

I hope, now prototype and __proto__  is simplified a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Another good way to understand it:

```js
var foo = {}

/* 
foo.constructor is Object, so foo.constructor.prototype is actually 
Object.prototype; Object.prototype in return is what foo.__proto__ links to. 
*/
console.log(foo.constructor.prototype === foo.__proto__);
// this proves what the above comment proclaims: Both statements evaluate to true.
console.log(foo.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
console.log(foo.constructor.prototype === Object.prototype);
```

Only after IE11 `__proto__` is supported. Before that version, such as IE9, you could use the `constructor` to get the `__proto__`.

Comment: Only that I would write it the other way around:
foo.__proto__ === foo.constructor.prototype

Answer (score 6):

### prototype

prototype is a property of a Function. It is the blueprint for creating objects by using that (constructor) function with new keyword.

### __proto__

`__proto__` is used in the lookup chain to resolve methods, properties. when an object is created (using constructor function with new keyword), `__proto__` is set to (Constructor) Function.prototype

```
function Robot(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var robot = new Robot();

// the following are true   
robot.__proto__ == Robot.prototype
robot.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype
```

### Here is my (imaginary) explanation to clear the confusion:

Imagine there is an imaginary class (blueprint/coockie cutter) associated with function. That imaginary class is used to instantiate objects. `prototype` is the extention mechanism (extention method in C#, or Swift Extension) to add things to that imaginary class.

```
function Robot(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

**The above can be imagined as:**

```
// imaginary class
class Robot extends Object{

    static prototype = Robot.class  
    // Robot.prototype is the way to add things to Robot class
    // since Robot extends Object, therefore Robot.prototype.__proto__ == Object.prototype

    var __proto__;

    var name = "";

    // constructor
    function Robot(name) {

        this.__proto__ = prototype;
        prototype = undefined;

        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**So,**

```
var robot = new Robot();

robot.__proto__ == Robot.prototype
robot.prototype == undefined
robot.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype
```

**Now adding method to the `prototype` of Robot:**

```
Robot.prototype.move(x, y) = function(x, y){ Robot.position.x = x; Robot.position.y = y};
// Robot.prototype.move(x, y) ===(imagining)===> Robot.class.move(x, y)
```

The above can be imagined as extension of Robot class:

```
// Swift way of extention
extension Robot{
    function move(x, y){    
        Robot.position.x = x; Robot.position.y = y
    }
}
```

**Which in turn,**

```
// imaginary class
class Robot{

    static prototype = Robot.class // Robot.prototype way to extend Robot class
    var __proto__;

    var name = "";

    // constructor
    function Robot(name) {

        this.__proto__ = prototype;
        prototype = undefined;

        this.name = name;
    }

    // added by prototype (as like C# extension method)
    function move(x, y){ 
        Robot.position.x = x; Robot.position.y = y
    };
}
```

Comment: still thinking of more coherent names for `__proto__` and prototype. maybe prototype and inheritance?

Comment: I would say, `prototype` & `__proto__` both should be avoided. We have class now and I like OOP.

Comment: the problem is that class is relatively new and it isn't supported by really convenient engines like microsoft JScript(nice to have when working on C and need a quick and dirty script engine that's always there), and nashorn javascript(which comes with all new Java installations under jjs and is a nice way of putting Java into a pure dynamic environment where you don't need to constantly recompile things). The thing is if class was sugar, it wouldn't be a problem, but it isn't, it offers things that are impossible without them in older js versions. Like extending "Function".

Comment: Eventually we will get support. I am backend developer, so I don't have issues, I code in js rarely.

Comment: and inheriting static members in a way that adding new/removing static members from parent is noticed by child(which I can't think of a way to do on JScript, which doesn't offer Object.assign/__proto__/getPrototypeOf, so you have to tinker with the root Object.prototype to simulate it)

Answer (score 6):

I've made for myself a small drawing that represents the following code snippet:

```
var Cat = function() {}
var tom = new Cat()
```

[image: Understanding __proto__ and prototype]

I have a classical OO background, so it was helpful to represent the hierarchy in this manner. To help you read this diagram, treat the rectangles in the image as JavaScript objects. And yes, functions are also objects. ;)

Objects in JavaScript have properties and `__proto__` is just one of them.

*The idea behind this property is to point to the ancestor object in the (inheritance) hierarchy.*

The root object in JavaScript is `Object.prototype` and all other objects are descendants of this one. The `__proto__` property of the root object is `null`, which represents the end of inheritance chain.

You'll notice that `prototype` is a property of functions. `Cat` is a function, but also `Function` and `Object` are (native) functions. `tom` is not a function, thus it does not have this property.

*The idea behind this property is to point to an object which will be used in the construction, i.e. when you call the `new` operator on that function.*

> Note that prototype objects (yellow rectangles) have another property called
>   `constructor` which points back to the respective function object. For
>   brevity reasons this was not depicted.

Indeed, when we create the `tom` object with `new Cat()`, the created object will have the `__proto__` property set to the `prototype` object of the constructor function.

In the end, let us play with this diagram a bit. The following statements are true:

- `tom.__proto__` property points to the same object as `Cat.prototype`.
- `Cat.__proto__` points to the `Function.prototype` object, just like `Function.__proto__` and `Object.__proto__` do.
- `Cat.prototype.__proto__` and `tom.__proto__.__proto__` point to the same object and that is `Object.prototype`.

Cheers!

Comment: Very well explained!

Comment: @theshinylight, `tom.__proto__` and `Cat.prototype` are stricly equal, So, `tom.__proto__ === Cat.prototype`  And  `Cat.prototype === tom.__proto__` are true. So, what did you mean by the arrow in the image ??

Comment: The black arrow (if you are referring to it) has no particular meaning, other than the property of the object. So `prototype` is property of the `Cat` object (from your question).

Comment: Brilliant explanation

Answer (score 4):

To put it simply:

```
> var a = 1
undefined
> a.__proto__
[Number: 0]
> Number.prototype
[Number: 0]
> Number.prototype === a.__proto__
true
```

This allows you to attach properties to X.prototype AFTER objects of type X has been instantiated, and they will still get access to those new properties through the __proto__ reference which the Javascript-engine uses to walk up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 4):

**Prototype or Object.prototype** is a property of an object literal. It represents the *Object* prototype object which you can override to add more properties or methods further along the prototype chain.

**__proto__** is an accessor property (get and set function) that exposes the internal prototype of an object thru which it is accessed.

*References:*

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype
2. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: `Object.prototype` is not a property of an object literal, trying to print out `{}.prototype` returns undefined; however, it can be accessed via `{}.__proto__`, which returns `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 3):

Explanatory example:

```
function Dog(){}
Dog.prototype.bark = "woof"

let myPuppie = new Dog()
```

now, myPupppie has `__proto__` property which points to Dog.prototype.

```
> myPuppie.__proto__
>> {bark: "woof", constructor: ƒ}
```

but myPuppie does NOT have a prototype property.

```
> myPuppie.prototype
>> undefined
```

So, `__proto__` of mypuppie is the *reference* to the .prototype property of constructor function that was used to instantiate this object (and the current myPuppie object has "delegates to" relationship to this `__proto__` object), while .prototype property of myPuppie is simply absent (since we did not set it).

Good explanation by MPJ here:
[**proto** vs prototype - Object Creation in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqGwxR_0d1M&index=5&list=PL0zVEGEvSaeHBZFy6Q8731rcwk0Gtuxub)

Answer (score 2):

#### DEFINITIONS

(number inside the parenthesis () is a 'link' to the code that is written below)

**`prototype`** - an object that consists of:
 => functions (3) of this
   particular `ConstructorFunction.prototype`(5) that are accessible by each
   object (4) created or to-be-created through this constructor function (1)
 => the constructor function itself (1)
 => `__proto__` of this particular object (prototype object)

**`__proto__`** (dandor proto?) - a link BETWEEN any object (2) created through a particular constructor function (1), AND the prototype object's properties (5) of that constructor THAT allows each created object (2) to have access to the prototype's functions and methods (4) (`__proto__` is by default included in every single object in JS)

#### CODE CLARIFICATION

1.

```
    function Person (name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;   
    }
```

2.

```
    var John = new Person(‘John’, 37);
    // John is an object
```

3.

```
    Person.prototype.getOlder = function() {
        this.age++;
    }
    // getOlder is a key that has a value of the function
```

4.

```
    John.getOlder();
```

5.

```
    Person.prototype;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try a 4th grade explanation:

Things are very simple. A `prototype` is an example of how something should be built. So:

- I'm a `function` and I build new objects similar to my `prototype`
- I'm an `object` and I was built using my `__proto__` as an example

**proof**:

```
function Foo() { }

var bar = new Foo()

// `bar` is constructed from how Foo knows to construct objects
bar.__proto__ === Foo.prototype // => true

// bar is an instance - it does not know how to create objects
bar.prototype // => undefined
```

Comment: Nope, neither `prototype` nor a `__proto__` are used on any time as a blueprint or so to create any object. This is a myth introduced by the blurry `class` syntax and it's predecessors. As the answer-post says it's just used for the lookup-chain and in case of `prototype` to identify `constructor` used with `new` (which is part of that pretend-to-be-classy mechanism that is confusing many users including me).

Comment: The first point should be "I'm a function and I build new objects that will delegate to my prototype"

Answer (score 1):

Every function you create has a property called `prototype`, and it starts off its life as an empty object. This property is of no use until you use this function as constructor function i.e. with the 'new' keyword.

This is often confused with the `__proto__` property of an object. Some might get confused and except that the `prototype` property of an object might get them the proto of an object. But this is not case. `prototype` is used to get the `__proto__` of an object created from a function constructor.

In the above example:

```js
function Person(name){
    this.name = name
}; 

var eve = new Person("Eve");

console.log(eve.__proto__ == Person.prototype) // true
// this is exactly what prototype does, made Person.prototype equal to eve.__proto__
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: `prototype` is not used to create the `__proto__` of an object. `__proto__`, when accessed, merely provides a reference to the `prototype` object.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `__proto__` for static methods?

```
function Foo(name){
  this.name = name
  Foo.__proto__.collection.push(this)
  Foo.__proto__.count++

}

Foo.__proto__.count=0
Foo.__proto__.collection=[]

var bar = new Foo('bar')
var baz = new Foo('baz')

Foo.count;//2
Foo.collection // [{...}, {...}]
bar.count // undefined
```

Comment: That's exactly why an answer to _"`__proto__` VS. `prototype` in JavaScript"_ ?

Comment: is it good or what about Foo.collection.push(this)
  Foo.count++

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function(){ 
      let a = function(){console.log(this.b)};
      a.prototype.b = 1;
      a.__proto__.b = 2;
      let q = new a();
      console.log(a.b);
      console.log(q.b) 
    })()
```

Try this code to understand

Answer (score 1):

There is only one object that is used for protypal chaining. This object obviously has a name and a value: `__proto__` is its name, and `prototype` is its value. That's all.

to make it even easier to grasp, look at the diagram on the top of this post (Diagram by dmitry soshnikov), you'll never find `__proto__` points to something else other than `prototype` as its value.

The gist is this: `__proto__` is the name that references the prototypal object, and `prototype` is the actual prototypal object.

It's like saying:

```
let x = {name: 'john'};
```

`x` is the object name (pointer), and `{name: 'john'}` is the actual object (data value).

*NOTE:* this just a massively simplified hint on how they are related on a high level.

***Update:*** Here is a simple concrete javascript example for better illustration:

```
let x = new String("testing") // Or any other javascript object you want to create

Object.getPrototypeOf(x) === x.__proto__; // true
```

This means that when `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` gets us the actual value of `x` (which is its prototype), is exactly what the `__proto__` of `x` is pointing to. Therefore `__proto__` is indeed pointing to the prototype of `x`. Thus `__proto__` references `x` (pointer of `x`), and `prototype` is the value of `x` (its prototype).

I hope it's a bit clear now.

Answer (score 1):

so many good answers exist for this question, but for recap and compact form of answer that have good details I add the following:

the first thing that we must consider is when JS was invented, computers have very low memory, so if we need a process for creating new object types, we must consider memory performance.

so they located methods that object created from that specific `object type` need, on the separate part of memory instead of every time we create a new object, store methods besides the object.
so if we reinvent the `new` operator and `constructor` function concept with JS's new features we have these steps:

1. and empty object. (that will be the final result of instantiation of object type)

```
let empty={}
```

2. we already know that for memory performance reasons all the methods that are needed for instances of an `object type` are located on the constructor function's `prototype` property. (functions are also objects so they can have properties)
   so we reference the `empty` object's `__protp__` to the location where those methods exist.
   (we consider the function that we use conceptually as the constructor, named constructor.

```
empty.__proto__ = constructor.prototype
```

3. we must initialize object type values.
   in JS function are disconnected from objects. with dot notation or methods like `bind` `call` `apply` that function objects have we must tell "what is the `this` context of the function".

```
let newFunc = constructor.bind(empty)
```

4. now we have a new function that has an `empty` object as `this` context.
   after execution of this function. the `empty` object will be filled, and the result of instantiation of type object will be this `empty` object if defined `constructor` function doesn't return(as if that will be the result of the process)

so as you see `__proto__` is a property of objects that refers to other objects(in JS functions are also object) `prototype` object property which consisted of properties that use across instances of a specific `object type`.

as you can guess from the phrase, `functions are objects`, functions also have `__proto__` property so they can refer to other object's `prototype` properties. this is how `prototype inheritance` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript/9959753#9959753) rightly stated

> `__proto__` is the actual object that is used in the lookup chain to
> resolve methods, etc.  prototype is the object that is used to build
> `__proto__` when you create an object with new:
>
> ```
> ( new Foo ).__proto__ === Foo.prototype;
> ( new Foo ).prototype === undefined;
> ```

We can further note that `__proto__` property of an object created using function constructor points towards the memory location pointed towards by *prototype* property of that respective constructor.

If we change the memory location of *prototype* of constructor function, `__proto__` of derived object will still continue to point towards the original address space. Therefore to make common property available down the inheritance chain, always append property to constructor function *prototype*, instead of re-initializing it (which would change its memory address).

Consider the following example:

```js
function Human(){
    this.speed = 25;
}

var himansh = new Human();

Human.prototype.showSpeed = function(){
  return this.speed;
}

console.log(himansh.__proto__ === Human.prototype); //true
console.log(himansh.showSpeed());   //25

//now re-initialzing the Human.prototype aka changing its memory location
Human.prototype = {lhs: 2, rhs:3}

//himansh.__proto__ will still continue to point towards the same original memory location. 

console.log(himansh.__proto__ === Human.prototype); //false
console.log(himansh.showSpeed());   //25
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain by a simple example:

```
function User(email, name){
    this.email = email;
    this.name = name;
    this.online = false;
    // method directly added to the constructor
    this.greet = ()=>{
        console.log(`Hi ${this.name}`);
    }
}
// Adding prototype method login to the constructor function. 
User.prototype.login = function(){
    this.online = true;
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
};
// Adding prototype method logout to the constructor function.
User.prototype.logout = function(){
    this.online = false;
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged out');
};
 
var userOne = new User('ryu@ninjas.com', 'Ryu');
var userTwo = new User('yoshi@mariokorp.com', 'Yoshi');
 
console.log(userOne);
userTwo.login();
userTwo.greet();
```

Output:
[image]

**Conclusion:**

- Properties and Methods added inside the **Constructor function** are
  added directly to the object.
- Properties and Methods added by
  **.prototype.** are added to the **`__proto__`** property of the object. We can even see those by `userOne.__proto__` or `userTwo.__proto__`

Answer (score -1):

my understanding is: __proto__ and prototype are all served for the prototype chain technique . the difference is functions named with underscore(like __proto__) are not aim for developers invoked explicitly at all. in other words, they are just for some mechanisms like inherit etc. they are 'back-end'. but functions named without underscore are designed for invoked explicitly, they are 'front-end'.

Comment: There are more to `__proto__` and `prototype`, than just the naming convention. They may or may not point to the same object. See @zyklus answer.

Comment: @demisx of course you said is right, but my opinion is name difference exposed the contrast of the functionality.

Comment: It's not just enough to state "as per your understanding", especially when other good answers have been provided before...

Answer (score -1):

`__proto__` is the base to construct `prototype` and a constructor function eg: `function human(){}` has `prototype` which is shared via `__proto__` in the new instance of the constructor function. A more detailed read [here](https://hackernoon.com/understand-nodejs-javascript-object-inheritance-proto-prototype-class-9bd951700b29)

Comment: @Derick Daniel: not sure why you down voted this but the edit you made was not that I was trying to convey. Edited it further for more clearance :).

Comment: Jyoti, i did not down vote your answer, someone else did, i just edited it :)

Answer (score -1):

This is a very important question relevant to anyone who wants to understand prototypical inheritance. From what I understand, prototype is assigned by default when an object is created with new from a function because Function has prototype object by definition:

```
function protofoo(){
}
var protofoo1 = new protofoo();
console.log(protofoo.prototype.toString()); //[object Object]
```

When we create an ordinary object without new, ie explicitly from a function, it doesn't have prototype but it has an empty **proto** which can be assigned a prototype.

```
var foo={
  check: 10
};
console.log(foo.__proto__); // empty
console.log(bar.prototype); //  TypeError
foo.__proto__ = protofoo1; // assigned
console.log(foo.__proto__); //protofoo
```

We can use Object.create to link an object explicitly.

```
// we can create `bar` and link it to `foo`
var bar = Object.create( foo );
bar.fooprops= "We checking prototypes";
console.log(bar.__proto__); // "foo"
console.log(bar.fooprops); // "We checking prototypes"
console.log(bar.check); // 10 is delegated to `foo`
```

Answer (score -1):

`__proto__` is created when the instance of class/function is created. Basically, it contains the prototype of the class/function of which the instance is created.
`prototype` contains the actual prototype which can be chained.

Answer (score -4):

!!!THIS IS THE BEST EXPLANATION IN THE WORLD!!!!!

```
var q = {}
var prototype = {prop: 11}

q.prop // undefined
q.__proto__ = prototype
q.prop // 11
```

in function constructors javascript engine call this `q.__proto__ = prototype` automatically  when we write `new Class`, and in to the `__proto__` prop set `Class.prototype`

```
function Class(){}
Class.prototype = {prop: 999} // set prototype as we need, before call new

var q = new Class() // q.__proto__ = Class.prototype
q.prop // 999
```

Enjoy %)