# When to use __proto__ and when to use prototype

Tags: javascript

All, I always confused by the `__proto__` and `prototype` properties of the object, Especially In the prototype inheritance chain, let's say there is an object named `test`, and the code is below.

```
test.add();//try to call a method name add.
```

in my understanding ,I draw a diagram to demo the flow of searching . But I am not sure if it is right .please help to review it .thanks.

[image]

**Corrected it based on the Minko Gechev's answer.**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \_\_proto\_\_ and prototype in Java script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/what-is-the-difference-between-proto-and-prototype-in-java-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only functions have `prototype` property but any object has `__proto__` property.

Usually it's not a good idea to change the `__proto__` property explicit better use something like `Object.create`.

Here is an example:

```
function Person() {
}
var proto = { bar: 'baz' };
Person.prototype = proto;
```

In this way any object which you create with the constructor function `Person` will have `__proto__` property referencing to `proto`

As conclusion we can say that:

The prototype property is used only for the constructor function it sets the `__proto__` property of all objects which will be created with this constructor function. When the interpreter is looking for property of a given object `foo` it firstly use the object `foo` after that `foo.__proto__` after that `foo.__proto__.__proto__` and so on while it find the property or not.

Comment: Not exactly. The `prototype` property is used only for the constructor function. When looking for property of an object you use `foo` after that `foo.__proto__` after that `foo.__proto__.__proto__` and so on.