# Why this behaviour?__proto__ vs prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
    function Obj1(name){
        this.__proto__={
            Name:name,
            getName:function(){
                alert(this.Name); 
            }


        };

    }

    function Obj2(name){
       this.prototype={
           Name:name,
           getName:function(){
           alert(this.Name); 
           };


       };

    }
    x=new Obj1("blue shark");
    z=new Obj2("red shark");
    x.getName();
    z.getName();// error:z.getName() is not a function
```

What is the difference between the two?Some say `prototype` is used for constructor functions only but in this case it doesn't work.... instead the `__proto__` work why?

Comment: It makes very little sense to set the prototype inside the constructor function. Furthermore __proto__ is not part of the ecma standard.

Comment: [Not yet](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-B.3.1), anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\_\_proto\_\_ Vs. prototype in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) (which is not standard (but might be soon))) sets an **object's** prototype.

[`.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited) sets the prototype of objects created by invoking the function it was set on as a constructor using `new`

Also worth mentioning is [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Here are examples:

Pseudo-classical with `.prototype`:

```
function Car(){
   this.x = 15;
}
Car.prototype.y = 10;

var g = new Car();
g.y; // this is 10;
```

Using `__proto__` (don't use this!):

```
var g = {x:15};
g.__proto__ = {y:10};
g.y; // this is 10;
```

This way is correct, and does not use constructors with `new`:

```
var g = Object.create({y:10}); //creates x with prototype {y:10}
g.x = 15;
g.y; // this is 10
```

Here is [an interesting tutorial on MDN covering these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited).

Comment: Here is an interesting comment by language creator Brandon Eich on `__proto__` by the way https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2010-April/010917.html

Comment: but `z = new Obj2()`,it was created using `new`

Comment: @RomanticElectron Read the answer and examples _carefully_ :) `.prototype` is set on the _constructor function_ . In your example, you'd be setting the `.prototype` of `Obj2` and not `this`.

Answer (score 2):

**Only functions has the property prototype.**
You need to set the prototype on the function self.

```
function Obj2(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Obj2.prototype={
    getName:function(){
       alert(this.Name); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`__proto__` is not a standard property.

Anyway every object created by `new` will get a prototype from the `.prototype` member **of the constructor** (a function). Note that the prototype member has no name, you cannot access it directly, you need `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)`.

If you want to create an object with a given prototype the code is `Object.create(proto)` that is more or less equivalent to

```
function makeObjectWithPrototype(x) {
    function makeit() { }
    makeit.prototype = x;
    return new makeit();
}
```

Comment: That's Crockford's old BEGET function :) With modern JS you can use `Object.create` instead (which has other benefits). Also, you can get an object's prototype using the standard `Object.getPrototypeOf`