# Best way to retrieve the prototype of a JS object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Trying to understand Prototypes in Javascript. For this example:

```
var obj = new Function();
obj.prototype.x = "a";
```

Why do I get different results from

```
console.log(obj.__proto__);
```

and

```
console.log(obj.prototype);
```

Thanks

Comment: proto==contructor.prototype

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this sentence mean: "In other words, obj.prototype is in general not the obj's {Prototype}."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075114/what-does-this-sentence-mean-in-other-words-obj-prototype-is-in-general-not-t), [Why this behaviour?__proto__ vs prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16394709/1048572) and mostly [__proto__ Vs. prototype in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
> var obj = new Function();
```

a new function object is created whose internal `[[Prototype]]` (or `__proto__` in browsers that support it) references `Function.prototype`, i.e. the built–in Function constructor's [public prototype](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.3.1) and assigned to the variable *obj*.

Because *obj* is a Function object, it has a *prototype* property by default just in case it is to be used as a constructor.

In:

```
> obj.prototype.x = "a";
```

a new *x* property is added to *obj.prototype* that is assigned a value of the string `'a'`. Note that *obj* only has a prototype property by default because it's a Function object.

So:

```
obj.prototype === obj.__proto__
```

is essentially:

```
obj.prototype === Function.prototype
```

which is clearly false.

So to answer the question "Best way to retrieve the prototype of a JS object" then you can access a constructor's public prototype through its *prototype* property.

You can access a instance's internal `[[Prototype]]` using ES5 [Object.getPrototypeOf](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2), however it may not be supported everywhere.

You can also access a instance's internal `[[Prototype]]` using the non–standard `__proto__` where supported.

A more general solution is to keep a reference to the constructor's prototype at the time the instance is created (since changing the constructor's *prototype* at some later stage will not change the `[[Prototype]]` of instances  that have already been created).

So in a general case you might do:

```
function Foo() {
  this.internalProto = Foo.prototype;
}

var foo = new Foo();

// ES5, where supported
Object.getPrototypeof(foo) == Foo.prototype; // true

foo.internalProto == Foo.prototype; // true

// Non–standard, Where supported
foo.internalProto == foo.__proto__;     // true
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

> `Object.prototype.__proto__`  points to the object which was used as
>   prototype when the object was instantiated.

It simply means that object used as prototype to create Function object was empty function, and that's why you have `function Empty() {}` in the output. You can observe it here:

```
console.log(Function.prototype);
var func = new Function();
console.log(func.__proto__);
console.log(func.prototype);
// OUTPUT:
// function Empty() {}
// function Empty() {}
// Object {}
```

`__proto__` of an empty object (e.g. `var a = {}`) is `Object {}` because this is, what was used to create base of your object (in other words `Object.prototype` was used). And `prototype` is not even available as a property of `a`, because you've created a totally empty object, so there's nothing.

Also notice that `__proto__` is now **deprecated**.

Why? I don't know, but I have never used it so I don't care :)

`prototype` is a different thing, e.g.

> Changes to the `Object prototype object` are propagated to all objects
>   unless the properties and methods subject to those changes are
>   overridden further along the prototype chain.

This is why you need `prototype` and you don't care about `__proto__` in real life. If I'm wrong please show me useful usage of `__proto__`.

Hope it's clearer now. And to answer your original question:

Prototype of a JS object can be retrieved only by using `prototype` property, as `__proto__` contains sth different. If `prototype` property doesn't exist, there is no prototype of the JS object, even if sth was used in the process of instantiation.

Comment: I believe `__proto__` is deprecated because it was never standardized, and has a replacement which is part of the standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf

Comment: You're right - just checked it - it's doing the same as `__proto__` but it's standarized: `var func = new Function();
console.log(func.__proto__);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(func));
console.log(func.prototype);`

Answer (score 0):

Accordint to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), obj.__proto__ has not been standardized.

So while obj.prototype has a clear standardized behav8our accross browsers, obj.__proto__ behaves differently in different browsers.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer the question, i.e. why `fnObj.prototype !== fnObj[[Prototype]]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this sideways...

`.prototype` and `.__proto__` are the same object (or are at one specific point in time)...

***BUUUUUT*** they're propertes of ***different*** objects.

```
var Human = function (name) {
    this.num_eyes = 2;
    this.num_heads = 1;
    this.name = name;
};
Human.prototype.die = function () { this.isAlive = false; };

var herman = new Human("Herman");

herman.__proto__.die === Human.prototype.die; // true
```

`.__proto__` is a link to the CONSTRUCTOR .prototype (and typically, is the SAME object)

It's almost like this:

```
var Human = function () {
    this = {};
    this.num_eyes = 2;
    // ......
    this.__proto__ = Human.prototype;
};
```

That isn't *exactly* how constructors work, but really, that's the idea.
And that's why `.__proto__` and `.prototype` aren't the same thing.
Because you're looking in the wrong place.

So if:

```
var herman = new Human();
herman.__proto__ === Human.prototype;
var Human = new Function ();
```

...so logic then states that `Human.__proto__ === Function.prototype;`

...and if `Human` and `Function` aren't the same object, then their `.prototype` properties aren't going to be the same (unless you overwrite one with the other `Human.prototype = Function.prototype;  Human.__proto__ === Human.prototype; //true`