# Confusion about 'this' and prototyping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having some confusion about implementing inheritance through prototyping and 'this' keyword in JavaScript.

```js
let person = {
  stomach: [],

  eat(food) {
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
};

let tony = {
  __proto__: person
};

let peter = {
  __proto__: person
};

tony.eat("shawarma");
alert( tony.stomach ); // shawarma


alert( peter.stomach ); // shawarma
```

In the above example, why does the last line gives the answer 'shawarma' even if nothing was pushed ?

Comment: Because JavaScript is looking for `peter.__proto__.stomach`. Refer https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes-emit.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394709/why-this-behaviour-proto-vs-prototype

Comment: Both `__proto__` point to the same object `person`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It does answer my question. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both `tony` and `peter` **share** the array, which is on `person`. There's only one array, you're just changing its state.

After you've created `tony` and `peter`, you have this in memory (omitting details):

```
                               +−−−−−−−−−−+                   
person−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−−>| (Object) |                   
                        / /    +−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | |    | stomach  |−−−−−>|  (Array)  | 
                        | |    +−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | |                      | length: 0 |
                        | |                      +−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
tony−−−−>| (Object)  |  | |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
         | __proto__ |−−+ |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
                          |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
peter−−−>| (Object)  |    |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
         | __proto__ |−−−−+
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Whether you access that array via `tony.__proto__.stomach` or `peter.__proto__.stomach` (via the prototype chain), you're accessing just that one array. When you push `"shawarma"` on it via `eat`, that one array's state is modifed, and visible regardless of which path you take to get to it:

```
                               +−−−−−−−−−−+                   
person−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−−>| (Object) |                   
                        / /    +−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | |    | stomach  |−−−−−>|    (Array)    | 
                        | |    +−−−−−−−−−−+      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ 
                        | |                      | length: 1     |
                        | |                      | 0: "shawarma" |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
tony−−−−>| (Object)  |  | |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+  | |
         | __proto__ |−−+ |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
                          |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
peter−−−>| (Object)  |    |
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+    |
         | __proto__ |−−−−+
         +−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

You'd solve this by giving `tony` and `peter` their **own** `stomach`s, and probably removing `stomach` from `person` (though you could leave it if you want to use `person` directly as well as using it as a prototype):

```js
let person = {
  stomach: [], // You may or may not want to remove this, depending
  eat(food) {
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
};

let tony = {
  __proto__: person,
  stomach: []
};

let peter = {
  __proto__: person,
  stomach: []
};

tony.eat("shawarma");
console.log(tony.stomach);  // shawarma

console.log(peter.stomach); // empty
```

Comment: I need to become _a lot faster_ to answer in crowded tags :(

Comment: @suraj: In this case, we both should have gone looking for duplicates rather than answering; I realized I was being silly and it didn't take long to find a dupetarget.

Answer (score 0):

`tony.hasOwnProperty("stomach")` will return false (since it is not what other OO languages call a **property**) and is now part of the prototype (like a **class property** or **static member**). A prototype is common to each object that uses it.

Therefore any object which has `person` as its `__proto__` or `prototype` will share the same `stomach`.

You can, with ES6, use this instead:

```
class Person{
  constructor(){
    this.stomach = [];
  }

  eat(food){
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
}

const tony = new Person();
const peter = new Person();

class RandomPelo extends Person{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.randomness = true;
  }

  eat(food){
    super.eat(food);
    this.weird_shared_stomach.push(food);  
  }
}

const pelo = new RandomPelo();
```

NB:
the `class` keyword is just syntactic sugar around the concept of **constructor function**, therefore you can also modify its prototype to add "static" properties:

`RandomPelo.prototype.weid_shared_stomach = [];`

Answer (score 0):

Because "stomach" is a property of prototype that is exactly the same for tony and peter objects. You need to reinitialize "stomach" property in constructor for every newly created object.

Also try to avoid reference to **proto** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

```
class Person {
    constructor() {
        // created separately for every new object
        this.stomach = [];
    }

    eat(food) {
        this.stomach.push(food);
    }
}

var tony = new Person();
var peter = new Person();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because both `tony` and `peter` share the same `person` prototype which contains `stomach` property.

When you trigger `tony.eat('shawarma')` the `eat` method is being launched with `this` pointing to the `person` object. So the person's stomach is being changed.

Everything will work well if you give `peter` and `tony` their own stomachs ;).

```
let person = {
  eat(food) {
    this.stomach.push(food);
  }
};

let tony = {
  stomach: [],
  __proto__: person
};

let peter = {
  stomach: [],
  __proto__: person
};
```

**EDIT:**
Just saw @wookieb answer - it's even better than mine.