# why instanceof keeps saying true after prototype changed?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

The `instanceof` operator should look at the prototype, no? Why does it not change its answer after the object's prototype has been changed? Example below:

```
// The .prototype of objects created with 'new MyKlass'
// is MyKlass.prototype
var MyKlass = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var xx = new MyKlass('xx', 20);
console.log(xx instanceof MyKlass);      // true, OK

xx.prototype = new String('s');
console.log(xx instanceof MyKlass);      // also true, WHY???
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This case is explained [in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) :

> Note that if the value of an instanceof test can change based on
>   changes to the prototype property of constructors, **it cannot be
>   changed by changing an object prototype**, because changing an object
>   prototype is not possible in standard ECMAScript.  It is however possible using the non-standard `__proto__` pseudo-property

This would log false :

```
xx.constructor.prototype = new String('s');
console.log(xx instanceof MyKlass);
```

In short, you shouldn't try to mutate JavaScript objects, they weren't designed to be mutable. I don't know what's your use case but there's probably a better solution, be it composition, internal state, or something's else.

Comment: Why can `prototype` of `MyKlass` change but not `xx.prototype`? Arent both `MyKlass` and `xx` objects?

Comment: @OliverWatkins Mutating an object is the general operation of changing its class. Most OOP (or POOP) languages don't let you do that because it's messy.

Comment: @zpzp I don't get your comment. Property access in JavaScript is often done via getters and setters, even if it's not directly visible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/what-is-the-difference-between-proto-and-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: so it _is_ possible on `MyKlass` but not on any random object?

Comment: When you set the `prototype` property of an object which isn't a function, you're adding a new property, you're not changing the internal `__proto__`. EDIT : Bergi explains it, see his answer for this point.

Answer (score 3):

It does not look at `.prototype` but [[prototype]], or what is available in some browsers as `.__proto__`

```
xx.__proto__ = new String("s");
console.log(xx instanceof MyKlass); 
//false
console.log(xx instanceof String); 
//true
```

Assigning a `.prototype` property to a non function has no effect except the normal assignment of any normal property really. And for functions that only has an effect when the function is used in `instanceof` check or called with `new`.

Comment: does setting `__proto__` have standard ECMAScript parallel (maybe in ES 5) ?

Comment: @zpzp no but it seems that it will be available in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Answer (score 3):

> The instanceof operator should look at the prototype, no?

Yes, it does. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

> Why does it not change its answer after the object's prototype has been changed?
>
> ```
> var xx = new MyKlass('xx', 20);
> xx.prototype = new String('s');
> ```

Because you didn't change the prototype of your `xx` object, but gave it a `prototype` property. `Object.getPrototypeOf(xx) === MyKlass.prototype` still applies. See [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/what-is-the-difference-between-proto-and-prototype-in-javascript) for details. What would work:

```
MyKlass.prototype = {}; // overwrite with a different object
console.log(xx instanceof MyKlass); // false now, xx doesn't inherit from the {}
```

or

```
xx.__proto__ = String.prototype; // or something
console.log(xx instanceof MyKlass); // false now, xx doesn't inherit from MyKlass.prototype
```

Notice that writing to the internal [[prototype]] via [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is non-standard in ES5

Comment: So the `.prototype` property of functions is special in a way, because setting it has meaning beyond just setting the property?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the object which instances or set to inherit from when the [function is called as a constructor with `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)