# Is this a subclass or new instance?

Tags: javascript, oop

I know JavaScript inheritence is much different than typical OO languages (Java, c++, etc.). Searching around, there also seems to be many different ways to create classes and class hierarchies. Because of this I'm confused about JavaScript inheritence.

Given the following code

```
if (!com) var com = {};
if (!com.foobar) com.foobar = {};

com.foobar.Foo = {
        foo : "foo",
        bar : "bar",
        baz : function () {
        return true;
        }
};
```

Why is the following not allowed? Why is com.foobar.Foo not a constructor? Is it because Foo is not a function, but an object?

```
var baz = new com.foobar.Foo();
```

Since I cannot do the above, how would I create a new Foo?

If I want to extend Foo, I thought I would do this:

> var bar = Object.create(com.foobar.Foo, {buz: {value: "neat"}});

.. but is bar a subtype of Foo or an instance of Foo? I'm leaning towards instance of Foo because the following prints 'undefine'

> console.log(bar.prototype);

Comment: Here's something nice http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx

Comment: Your "Foo" isn't a constructor because it's not even a function. It's just an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you can't do `var baz = new com.foobar.Foo();` because `Foo` is an object, not a function.

`Object.create` is used to set the *prototype* of a variable (i.e. `bar.prototype = Object.create(/*etc etc*/)`).  For more information, see the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Using `Object.create` properly results in `bar` being another object with the `prototype` of `Foo`.  This means that anything `Foo` has can be used on `bar`, eg `bar.bar === 'bar'` (if that makes sense).  Changes to `Foo` will be reflected in `bar`, but not the other way around.  It's not *quite* a subtype.  (JS is weird, but it's delightfully so.)

For more on this, check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Then why is bar.prototype undefined?

Comment: Apologies, I made an assumption in my explanation.  I've updated the question, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no classes, only objects. When you create an object, it can also have a **prototype**, which is **just another object** that the created object will use to *delegate* calls to properties (or functions) it doesn't itself understand.

This works more or less like classic inheritance, since subclasses also delegate calls it doesn't understand to superclasses.

So, taking that lead, you'd like to make `Foo` a prototype for other objects you create; `Foo` would act somewhat like a superclass to the objects.

A handy function you already know about is the `Object.create`. You can use it to create a new object with a specific prototype, as you did:

```
var bar = Object.create(com.foobar.Foo, {buz: {value: "neat"}});
```

This means that `bar` will have a prototype of `Foo` and also will have an **own property** (i.e. not in the prototype) of `buz`.

Now, the prototype of `bar`, which points to `Foo`, can be found (at least in Chrome, since this is implementation specific) on the property `__proto__`. So this is `true`: `bar.__proto__ === com.foobar.Foo`.

Moving forward, if you want `bar` to also be a <s>superclass</s> prototype of another object, you'd do the same:

```
var subbar = Object.create(bar);
```

Makes sense? I'll later add more about `Function`, the property `prototype` and the `new` operator if you want....

Comment: I only knew of *.prototype and not __proto__. Based on your answer, I looked up the difference between the two (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript). Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to instantiate Foo because it is an object, not a function. You can accomplish that by creating a function and using prototype to set the instance methods:

```
// constructor method
com.foobar.Foo = function() {
    this.foo = 'foo'
    this.bar = 'bar'
}

com.foobar.Foo.prototype.baz = function() {
    return true
}
```

Take a look at it running on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DE7KZ/