# What is - function Empty() - in javascript ?

Tags: javascript

I have this function :

`function fff(){}`

Which is a `function` which is an instance of `Function constructor`

so `fff.__proto__` should show me  : `function Function() { [native code] }`

But it doesn't.

It shows :  `function Empty() {}`

[image]

It is only at the `constructor` property of `__proto__` that I see `function Function() { [native code] }`

**Question :**

What is this `function Empty() {}` function
and why `fff.__proto__` won't show me  : `function Function() { [native code] }`  ?

nb
I know that `__proto__` is the actual object that is used in the lookup chain to resolve methods, etc. `prototype` is the object that is used to **build** `__proto__` when you create an object with `new`.

But again : function `fff` is a function which is instantiated behind the scenes by newing `Function constructor.`...so ?

Comment: @duri new && age<18...

Comment: Your `nb` is incorrect.

Comment: @SLaks http://stackoverflow.com/a/9959753/859154

Comment: the Empty function is for display purposes within the console in chrome

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That is slightly incorrect; `__proto__` _is_ the ctor's `prototype` (note that `( new Foo ).__proto__ === Foo.prototype` is true)

Comment: empty means it doesn't inherit anything

Comment: @ArunKillu `Empty` still inherits from `Object.prototype`. It just has an *empty* block and no named arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski John resig was very careful and said "attached" and not "inherits". ( in his book http://i.stack.imgur.com/q5F24.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `__proto__`.

`__proto__` returns the prototype value that the object inherits; not its constructor.

All functions (including `Function` itself) inherit `Function.prototype`.
Thus, `Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype` is true.
This object is specified in section [15.3.4](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4) of the spec:

> The Function prototype object is itself a Function object (its `[[Class]]` is `"Function"`) that, when invoked, accepts any arguments and returns undefined.

See also

> ### 15.3.4.2 Function.prototype.toString ( )
>
> An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This representation has the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration*. Note in particular that the use and placement of white space, line terminators, and semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent.
>
> The `toString` function is not generic; it throws a TypeError exception if its this value is not a Function object. Therefore, it cannot be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

Comment: _proto is the ctor's prototype_--- that helped a lot. thanks slaks. ( i was sure that it is the constructor)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No; that's the `constructor` property (which comes from the prototype)

Comment: I guess the _NO_ part is for my second cpart of the comment

Comment: - So can you please tell me - why in this [code](http://jsbin.com/OrAGOrU/2/edit) I dont see the alert while in [this](http://jsbin.com/ULACixI/2/edit) one - i do see the alert ? if I create an instance from newing a function - it should go to the Function.prototype....no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No.  `MyFunction.prototype` is not a function; it's an object that instances of your function will inherit.  See http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.2

Comment: I didnt write `MyFunction.prototype` I wrote `Function.prototype`, and I still dont understand why the first one is not working while the other does

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Your function's `prototype` (which its instances inherit) is not a function and does not inherit `Function.prototype`.

Comment: But `new myFunc()` is an Object. and Object is a function : >> `function Object() { [native code] }` so it is an instance of Function ctor....no ? ( thank you very much for answering)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No.  It inherits `Object.prototype`, not `Object`.  You're confusing constructor inheritance ("X is an instance of Y") with prototype inheritance ("X's prototype is Y")