# Javascript __proto__ - clarification?

Tags: javascript

I have this function  :

`function Foo(){}`

According to this picture :

[image]

```
>> Foo.prototype   ->    Foo {}
```

[image]

So if I write :

> > Foo.prototype.constructor

Now - it references to the *constructor function* which created the  `Foo{}` object which is `function Foo(){}`

[image]

All ok.

So where is  the question ?

`Foo.prototype` is an object instance --> `Foo {}`

And who is the constructor function  of `Foo{}` ?

it is the the `function Foo(){}`

you can see it here in yellow :

[image]

ok

But I was told [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640683/what-is-function-empty-in-javascript) that :

[image]

So `Foo.prototype.__proto__` should reference to the `prototype` of `function Foo(){}`   and not to `Object.prototype` !

If I translate it :

```
    __proto__               is the                   ctor's                        prototype
    _________________________________________________________________________________________
  Foo.prototype.__proto__     is the               function Foo(){}               Foo.prototype
```

but this is wrong

And i'm probably wrong because :

[image]

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: First off, `__proto__` is non-standard, use `Object.getPrototypeOf`, though for shortness, and because I'm lazy, I did use `prototype` quite a few times in this answer*

Well, you're thrown of by your initial assumption, if I'm reading you correctly:

```
Foo.prototype -> Foo{}
```

The prototype of `Foo` (which is a constructor) is, by definition an instance of `Foo`. But, because a constructor is a function, and a constructor returns an object of a particular instance, the prototype will be an augmented `Object` either way.
I'm not a big fan of comparing prototypal ineritance to classical OOP, but think of it like this:

The `Foo` prototype is sort of a mutable class definition (you can add methods and properties as you go along), the constructor creates an object that *augments* this prototype, and adds another layer of properties/methods on an instance level.
Hence `Foo.prototype instanceof Foo` is true. But, `Foo` being an object:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype) === Object.prototype
```

is true. Just as

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Array.prototype) === Object.prototype.
```

Translate this to JS (prototype)-speak, and you get something like:

For each function object JS creates, this object is assigned a `prototype` property. The `prototype` property is an instance of `Object`, but it has 1 special property.
If one attempts to access a property or method on an object, and JS cannot find this property defined at the instance level, JS will attempt to resolve the name on the prototype property:

```
instance.nonExistantProperty;
//js scans instance variable, doesn't find property:
instance.prototype.nonExistantProperty
//js uses prototype, if not found:
instance.prototype.prototype.nonExistantProperty
//all the way up to Object.prototype, which does not have a prototype, so here an exception is raised (TypeError is thrown)
```

Here's a short schematic representation of this lookup, which I copied from [one of my older posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174505/1230836), it might be worth a look, also check the linked answers at the bottom, they go into even more details on this matter

```
[      F.divide      ]<=========================================================\ \
F[divide] ===> JS checks instance for property divide                           | |
 /\ ||                                                                          | |
 || || --> property found @instance, return value-------------------------------| |
 || ||                                                                          | |
 || ===========> Function.prototype.divide could not be found, check prototype  | |
 ||      ||                                                                     | |
 ||      ||--> property found @Function.prototype, return-----------------------| |
 ||      ||                                                                     | |
 ||      ==========> Object.prototype.divide: not found check prototype?        | |
 ||          ||                                                                 | |
 ||          ||--> property found @Object.prototype, return---------------------|_|
 ||          ||                                                                 |=|
 ||          =======>prototype is null, return "undefined.divide"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|X|
 ||                                                                             \ /
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~< TypeError can't read property 'x' of undefined
```

That's basically it.

Now, perhaps you're also a tad thwarted as to why `Foo.prototype.constructor` references the `Foo` function.
Again, this is quite easy, because each instance is expected to contain all information you might require to determine which type of object you're dealing with:

```
function Foo{}
var inst = new Foo();
console.log(inst.constructor);//references the constructor function
```

Remember, all instances returned by `Foo` return an object, that references all of the `prototype` properties, and (optionally) some properties at instance level, too.

Why, then, would you even bother creating such instances? Again this is perfectly simple: changing an instance, does not change the prototype:

```
console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor === inst.constructor);//true
inst.constructor = function(){};//override constructor property
console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor === inst.constructor);//false, prototype did not change
```

Comment: I'm sorry  - I didnt understand the _"augmented Object either way"_ part. `Foo.prototype` is `Foo{}` **instance Object**. and __proto__ should reference to its ctor's prototype.  so who is `Foo{}` ctor ? it is the `Function Foo(){}` . ( and again - i'm wrong) proof --http://i.stack.imgur.com/n4PMC.png.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `Foo{}`'s constructor is `Foo.prototype.constructo`, because `Foo.prototype` is `Foo{}`, just like, on your screenshot `g.constructor` is `functoin Foo`. The `Foo.prototype`, like I said, is an automatically assigned property, like an array has a magic length prop. But basically, a prototype is just an `Object`, so its _real_ constructor is the object constructor, but because this prototype belongs to a constructor function, its constructor property is set to reference that function. That's all really

Comment: I think you're right becuase here (http://i.stack.imgur.com/qXy97.png) I  see that `new Object()`'s `__proto__` is indeed `object.prototype`. and there is no difference between `new Foo()` vs `Foo{}`

Comment: I've been thinking of it again and it doesn't fit (in my head): what do you mean by _"its real constructor"_ ? the ctor of `Foo{}` is `function Foo()` and the prototype is `Foo.prototype` so why does  `Foo{}'s` `__proto__` **which should refer its ctor prototype** - refers to `Object.prototype` ?

Comment: All objects come with a prototype. This prototype is an object all on its own. You may have seen people do this: `Foo.prototype = { someF: function(){}, anotherF: function(){}}`. A prototype is just _a property of a constructor, that happens to be an object_. Hence, all prototypes are just objects, and their actual constructor is `Object`. The `constructor` property just refers back to the constructor the prototype obkect belongs to. Nothing in your code refers to the `object.prototype` directly, but at the root of every object, lies the `Object.prototype`