# Chrome's Object display?

Tags: javascript

*I may not reading chromes object display as I should :*

I have this code :

```
function Foo(){};
var g= new Foo();
```

Also - ( console code) :

```
>>Foo.prototype //  Foo {}
```

**Question :**

Does it say its type is instance of `Foo` ? or just a `plain` regular object ?

*p.s. - I've heard that prototype is a regular object. so the Foo word in `Foo{}`  makes me think it is an instance of `Foo`*

Why am I asking ?

Because running this :

`Foo.prototype.__proto__`

shows `Object {}` and not its instance constructor prototype which is : `Foo.prototype` ...

Additional info :

*Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677348/javascript-proto-clarification) of mine ( which doesn't talks about the way chrome displays objects* :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo.prototype` has a property `constructor`, which is defined as `Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;`
and **that's why** the console shows it like that

That's the consequence of `Foo.prototype` having a `constructor` property. Each prototype of a constructor function has a `constructor` property which points back to that function, e.g.

```
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;
```

Now, it looks like in order to determine which constructor function an object is an instance of, Chrome's console looks at the `constructor` property of an object and then assumes that the object is an instance of that function.
This works in almost all cases, but not for prototype objects, because they have explicitly set a `constructor` property.

Example:

```
> function Foo() {}
undefined
> Foo.prototype.constructor = function xyz() {}
function xyz() {}
> Foo.prototype
xyz {}
```

Another, simpler example:

```
> var obj = {};
> obj
Object {}
> obj.constructor = function xyz() {};
function xyz() {}
> obj
xyz {}
```

As you can see, the console is really just looking at the `constructor` property of an object (which is usually inherited) and then prints the function name of the function assigned to it.

`Foo.prototype.constructor` is just a normal property which is assigned when a function is created.
It's purpose is that **actual instances** of `Foo` (created with `new Foo`) have a constructor property which points to Foo.
Since instances inherit all properties from the prototype.

Comment: I don't understand : what is the  `Foo.prototype` type ?

Comment: which is type is Foo instance. `Foo{}`....right ? (that's what the cosnsole shows)

Comment: Yes, but only because an instance inherits the `constructor` property from the prototype. Chrome's `console.log` looks at the `constructor` property of an object and then assumes that the object is an instance of that object. This works in almost all cases, but not for prototype objects, because they have explicitly set a `constructor` property.

Comment: ok so if the type is `Foo` and `__proto__` is ctor's prototype - why `Foo.prototype.__proto__` doesnt refer to Foo.prototype ?

Comment: `g.__proto__` refers to `Foo.prototype`, which is a "plain" object. And the prototype of a plain object is `Object.prototype`.

Comment: sory . i meant `Foo.prototype.__proto__` . `Foo.prototype` is instance of `Foo{}` so its __proto__ should referr to its ctor prototype...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40434/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-felix-kling)

Comment: Awww... But it was interesting :(

Comment: @aychedee you can see the chat content you know ...:-)

Comment: Oh, so you can! Excellent.