# Creating a function object linked with other function?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I know,

- We can create new object & link given object as its prototype using
  `Object.create()`.
- We can create new object using `new` keyword
  with any function, which creates an object linked with that function's
  prototype object.

But, I see in the browser console, some functions like `HTMLBodyElement`, `HTMLElement`, `XMLHttpRequest`,

`HTMLElement.__proto__ === Element`

`HTMLElement` is a **function** and its prototype is `Element` which is also a **function**. My question is how `HTMLElement` has been created and how its prototype has been linked with `Element` function. What is the syntax they have used to create HTMLElement ?

Comment: Those are **host objects**. They can be created in any way as the environment sees fit.

Comment: @FelixKling I was just curious to see, how we create a function like that whose prototype is linked to another function ?

Answer (score 2):

As Felix Kling pointed out in his comment, the functions in question are provided by the environment. Thus without reading through the sporce code of the browser's JS engine or - if you're lucky - its documentation, you won't find out "how `HTMLElement` has been created".

But I suppose your question is rather how to create a construct like that yourself, which is fairly easy. The following is one of several approaches you have to your avail.

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = Element.prototype;
```

Verify with:

```
(new Foo()) instanceof Element
```

For example in your console and you'll get `true`. I'd rather call this a *mixin*, somehow.

Another way is, keeping `Foo` as the constructor:

```
Foo.prototype = new Bar();
```

Where `Bar` is the "parent" class. This has the advantage that functions and variables created in the constructor are available to the child class as well. Note that `Element` will not allow you to construct a new instance directly, hence I chose a different parent.

If you want to add more methods and fields, you can do so after "linking" the prototype (your words):

```
Foo.prototype.foobar = "foobar";
Foo.prototype.getFoobar = function() {
    return this.foobar;
}
```

Or do so in the constructor.

**Prototypal inheritance** is ingenius and a fun thing, but can be quite hard to understand. Play around a little.

### Update

Regarding OP's supposed misunderstanding (see comments), do not confuse `prototype` with `__proto__`.

Generally speaking `__proto__` stores the `prototype` of the object's constructor. In this context, this means `(new Foo()).__proto__ === Foo.prototype`. `__proto__` stores the methods and fields shared among **instances** of a class.

Consequently, `Foo.__proto__ === Function.prototype === Empty` has nothing to do with the inheritance of actual instances of the class `Foo`.

Refer to the following two questions for further information:

- [What is - function Empty() - in javascript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640683/what-is-function-empty-in-javascript)
- [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks Derija93, In both of above implementations, Foo's prototype(Foo.__proto__) is Empty(which Function.prototype). I think, Foo could be implemented something like: function Foo(){}; Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo, Element); In which Foo's prototype(Foo.__proto__) will be the Element function. May be the same way HTMLElement has been implemented. I am not sure.

Comment: There is a substantial difference between `prototype` and `__proto__`. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640683/what-is-function-empty-in-javascript) for more information. In a nutshell, `prototype` is used to construct `__proto__` which refers to the methods and fields shared among instances. `Foo.__proto__ === Function.prototype` and `(new Foo).__proto__ == Foo.prototype`. I'll expand my answer with the references for future readers.