# Javascript Objects Inside Prototype

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When learning angularjs I found out that if you put objects in a prototype object , the instances that inherit from that prototype would change the prototype's objects on assigning.

Example :

```
function Person(name) {this.name = name;}
Person.prototype = {species : "homo-sapiens" , characteristics : { "legs" : 2 , "height" : 175}}
var joe = new Person("joe"); 
joe.characteristics.legs = 1 ; 
console.log(Person.prototype.characteristics) //Object {legs: 1, height: 175}
```

What I showed is that the prototype's instance (joe) changed the object's value on the prototype itself because it inherited an object (characteristics) and not a primitive.

My question is as follows : Are prototypes meant most of the time to hold primitives? (in most cases , you would never want an instance to change the prototype's value. Angular.js actually does so , but it's in the rare case where you actually want a child instance to write to the prototype) . And what would you do if you actually wanted to put an object on the prototype without the instances writing to the prototype on assigning?

Comment: Most frameworks that provide "`classes`" provide methods to clone primitives on the prototype to each instance of the `class`. You may want to make a wrapper function for classes if this is desired

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really related to `prototype`, but just a general JS behavior.

The solution would be to copy the object from the prototype in the constructor,

```
function Person() {
    this.characteristics = angular.copy(this.characteristics);
}

Person.prototype = { whatever };
```

The above assumes angular is available for the `angular.copy` function. Otherwise you would need to manually do a copy of the object by iterating the properties and copying into a new one.

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior you're expecting, try this:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.species = "homo-sapiens";  
    this.characteristics = { "legs" : 2 , "height" : 175};
}
// NOTE: line below is no longer needed, but I'm keeping it 
// here just so you can see its output for comparison below
Person.prototype = {species : "homo-sapiens", 
                    characteristics : { "legs" : 2 , "height" : 175}}

var joe = new Person("joe"); 

joe.species = "regular old joe"; 
console.log('Person.prototype.species:', Person.prototype.species); 
// Line above prints: Person.prototype.species: homo-sapiens
console.log('joe.species:', joe.species); 
//joe.species: regular old joe

joe.characteristics.legs = 1 ; 
console.log('Person.prototype.characteristics:', Person.prototype.characteristics); 
//Person.prototype.characteristics: Object {legs: 2, height: 175}
console.log('joe.characteristics:', joe.characteristics); 
//joe.characteristics: Object {legs: 1, height: 175}
```

To clarify, your question really has nothing to do with angular, it just has to do with javascript's prototype based inheritance and how it works.

You may want to checkout [this article on prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

You may also want to [check out this SO question on `__proto__` vs prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript).