# What does this sentence mean: "In other words, obj.prototype is in general not the obj's {Prototype}."

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the `new` word in javascript. The top answer here [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) recommends [this](http://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html) article.

In that article, in the prototypes section, the author says:

> In other words, obj.prototype is in general not the obj's {Prototype}.

What does this mean? I have a hazy understanding of prototype (object that begets other objects). I understand that javascript does not have classes in the way that C# and Java have classes. Is that what the sentence above is expressing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that article is the best way to understand what's going on here - it's a great technical explanation, but perhaps not the best way to get an intuitive understanding.

Let's step back and work this through.

#### A quick look at property lookup

One way to understand prototypal inheritance is to think of it as way to say "if I don't have it, look over there".

Say you've got an object and try to access a property that doesn't exist, JS will return the value `undefined`:

```
var x = {};
x.foo //=> undefined
```

All objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, so look what happens if we modify it:

```
var x = {};
x.foo //=> undefined

Object.prototype.foo = 'hello there';
x.foo //=> 'hello there';
```

What happened? When we initially create x, JavaScript sets up an internal `[[Prototype]]` property that points to `Object.prototype`. Effectively, there is a lookup algorithm that looks something like (pseudo-code):

```
Lookup(obj, prop) = 
  if HasProperty(object, property)
    return GetPropertyValue(object, property)
  else if HasPrototype(object)
    return Lookup(PrototypeOf(object), property)
  else
    return undefined
```

In other words, start with the initial object, check for the property, if it doesn't have it, follow the prototype chain to keep looking for it. If we hit the end of the prototype chain, the property must be undefined.

#### So what about the `new` operator?

The `new` operator gives us a way to:

1. dynamically set the prototype of an object to something other than `Object.prototype`
2. do some initialization stuff when we create an object

NOTE: in ES5, we also have [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which gives you 1, but not 2.

When you say `new Foo(a, b)`, here's what happens:

1. we make a new object that has its internal `[[Prototype]]` set to `Foo.prototype`.
2. we run the function `Foo` (its just a normal function) with its context (think `this`) set to the new object we just made
3. we return the new object after the function finishes (actually, if the function explicitly returns a value, we just return that value, but most of the time, we won't be doing that).

But wait, where did `Foo.prototype` come from?

Let's see - run the following in the console:

```
function Foo() {}
typeof Foo.prototype //=> "object"
```

When we create a function in JS, it comes with an object attached to its `prototype` property. It's just an object, like any other, so you can manipulate it, set/delete properties, even completely overwrite it (which the mentioned article shows an example of).

For example:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.answer = 42;
var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();

foo1.answer //=> 42
foo2.answer //=> 42

// If you want you can change foo2's answer
foo2.answer = 'something else';

// Foo.prototype is unchanged
Foo.prototype.answer //=> 42
foo1.answer //=> 42 (still getting its answer from the prototype)
foo2.answer //= 'something else'
```

#### Getting back to the original question

Continuing with the foo example from above, what the original article was referring to is that `foo1` and `foo2` don't have `prototype` properties set on them:

```
foo1.prototype //=> undefined
foo2.prototype //=> undefined
```

NOTE: there is a non-standard [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) that many JS engines provide that *will* give you an object's prototype, and in ES5, you also have [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get access to a given object's prototype.

#### Relevant links:

- [MDN's page on the `new` operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)
- [MDN's page on "working with objects".](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: great answer. But in your second-to-last example, why does foo2.answer return 12 instead of returning 'something else'.

Comment: Good catch - I had initially used 12 and then decided to change it for some reason and forget to update it in both places. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that javascript does not have classes in the way that C# and Java have classes. Is that what the sentence above is expressing?

No. While true, it has nothing to do with that sentence.

> > In other words, obj.prototype is in general not the obj's {Prototype}.
>
> What does this mean?

An object might have a {prototype} (usually referred to as *[[prototype]]*), which is the object from which it does inherit properties. You can access that via the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` function, it is not a "visible" property of the object but some "hidden field".

Also, some objects (especially function objects) do have a `.prototype` property, i.e. a public attribute with the literal name "prototype".

The sentence states that these two "prototypes" are different from each other.

The question you linked now explains how the `new` keyword relates these different "prototypes". When you call a constructor function with `new`, then a new instance is created. The instance does inherit (its [[prototype]] will be set to) the prototype object of the "class" (which is shared amongst all instances) and that is looked up via the `.prototype` property of the constructor function.

As an example, let's look at the `ObjMaker` function from the code there. The `ObjMaker.prototype` (property) is the base for all ObjMaker instances. However, `Object.getPrototypeOf(ObjMaker)` is the object from which all function objects inherit from ([[prototype]]), which is `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence means that you can't access an object's prototype using `obj.prototype`. You can access it with `obj.__proto__` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` though. Also see the question [__proto__ Vs. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

The article is a bit dated. What it means is that `prototype` is a property. A property of a function object to be precise. It provides a way to define a prototype for objects created with this function. E.g.:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.myMethod = function() {};

var myFoo = new Foo();
```

`myFoo` is an object and it has a prototype that contains the method `myMethod`.

The prototype of myFoo is **not** `myFoo.prototype`. That doesn't even exist.

Comment: What do you mean by "dated"? The article seems to explain it quite well and even is correct (maybe apart from the "initialiser inheritance" section).

Comment: @Bergi "dated" means based on ECMAScript v3. I doesn't matter in terms of constructors, which is the main topic, but we now have `Object.getPrototypeOf`, e.g.