# javascript OOP inherit methods to multiple DOM elements

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I need a way to add new methods to the existing one on some DOM elements (in my case, canvas). I want to do something like this :

```
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.foo = function(){
  console.log('foo' + this.id);
}
c.bar = function(){
  console.log('bar' + this.id);
}
```

Because it will be used for several canvas elements I don't want to write this code each time.

I could use a method that add this methods to all of my elements, but I was wondering if there is a way to **do this with OOP** (inheritance ?).

Could I do something like this ?

```
var extendedCanvas = function(){
  this.foo = function(){
    console.log('foo' + this.id);
  };
  this.bar = function(){
    console.log('bar' + this.id);
  }
}
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.prototype = new extendedCanvas();
c.foo();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.prototype = new extendedCanvas();
c.foo();
```

Nope, assigning anything to the [`.prototype` property of an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572) does not have any effect. You could add your methods to [`HTMLCanvasElement.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement), but [extending the native DOM is considered a bad practise](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Instead, try the [mixin pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mixinpatternjavascript):

```
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas');
extendedCanvas.call(c); // give properties .foo and .bar to 'c' instance
c.foo();
```

Comment: i love `Learning JavaScript Design Patterns by Addy Osmani`, thanks for introduction

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your functions directly onto the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) object like this :

```
Element.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo' + this.id);
}
Element.prototype.bar = function(){
    console.log('bar' + this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, if `classA` wants to be inherited from `classB`, prototype of `ClassA` must be set by an instance of `classB`....

```
function classB()
{
    this.Name = "";
}
classB.prototype.func = function(){};

function classA()
{
}
classA.prototype = new classB();
```

now `Name` and `func` are on every instance of `classA`

and if you want more things on `classA` you can then do this:

```
function classA()
{
    this.Family = "";
}
classA.prototype = new classB();
classA.prototype.func_new = function(){};
```

`Family` and `func_new` are only on every instance of `classA` not `classB`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach to extend canvas... something like `decorator pattern`:

```
    function DecoratedCanvas(id) {

        this.Canvas = document.getElementById(id);

        this.foo = function () { console.log('foo' + this.Canvas.id); };
        this.bar = function () { console.log('bar' + this.Canvas.id); }
    };

    var o = new DecoratedCanvas("myCanvas");
    o.foo();
    o.bar();
    var c = o.Canvas;
```