# JS - What is the difference between using "new" and passing an object as context to a constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype, instance

```
function dog(){
    this.barking = "woof";
    this.bark = function(){console.log(this.barking)}   
}

var tony = new dog();

var stark = {}; 
dog.call(stark);

tony.bark();// "woof"
stark.bark();// "woof"

console.log(tony.prototype == stark.prototype);// true
console.log(tony.__proto__ == stark.__proto__);// false

console.log(tony instanceof dog)//true
console.log(stark instanceof dog)//false

console.log(tony.constructor == stark.constructor);// false

console.log(tony.constructor.toString() == tony.constructor.toString());// true
```

What is the difference causing those results ?

Why do Tony and Stark have the same prototype but not the same proto and constructor ? (I guess instanceof results are different because of *_* proto __ )

Detailed answers are very welcome

Comment: stark is an object literal, while tony isn't that explains why the constructor is different

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference causing those results?

Understand [how `new` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572). In your case `new dog()` is almost equivalent to `dog.call(Object.create(dog.prototype))`.

> Why do Tony and Stark have the same prototype

Actually neither of them have a `.prototype`. You're getting `true` because `undefined == undefined`. Only the `dog` constructor [has a `.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572).

> but not the same proto and constructor? (I guess instanceof results are different because of `__proto__`)

The `constructor` is inherited from the prototype, and that one is different.

It is different because of the different ways they were constructed - one using `new` inherits from `dog.prototype`, while the other using an object literal `{}` inherits from `Object.prototype`.

See also [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword uses a ECMAScript function called `[[Construct]]`. Let's step through [what `[[Construct]]` does in ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) with a constructor function called *F*:

> 1) Let *obj* be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
>
> 2) Set all the internal methods of *obj* as specified in 8.12.
>
> 3) Set the `[[Class]]` internal property of *obj* to `"Object"`.
>
> 4) Set the `[[Extensible]]` internal property of *obj* to true.

Okay, so far we've just set up a plain object, called *obj*. We will eventually use *obj* as the constructor function's `this` value, when we get around to invoking the constructor *F*.

> 5) Let *proto* be the value of calling the `[[Get]]` internal property of *F* with argument `"prototype"`.
>
> 6) If Type(*proto*) is Object, **set the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of *obj* to *proto*.**
>   ...
>
> 8) Let *result* be the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal property of F, **providing `obj` as the `this` value**...

Here is where the magic happens: when we call `new F()`, the new object we use for `this` has its internal `[[Prototype]]` property (accessible with `__proto__`) set to `F.prototype`.

This special step does **not** happen with `F.call(someObj)`, because in that case, the `this` value of the `F` call is supplied by `call`, not by the JavaScript engine going through the `[[Construct]]` steps. Thus, the object passed into the `F.call` has the same prototype chain before and after the call.