# Difference between the prototype property of a JS constructor and it's prototype

Tags: javascript

Constructor:

```
function Team (type) {
  this.type = type;
}

//this will output this empty object inherited from Object.property
console.log(Team.prototype);
-> Team {}

//this one outputs nothing in my console
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Team));
//is it inheriting from this one, the one for all functions?
-> Function.prototype //??
```

What is the difference between the `.prototype` property and `Object.getPrototypeOf`? 
What's else does Function.prototype (the one that all functions and constructors inherit from) prototype do, except for storing properties?

Comment: Is the question "why does `Team` have a property `getPrototypeOf`"?

Comment: Question is what's the difference between `Team.prototype` and `Team.getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: I think you want `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Team))` to view the objects that all functions inherit from.

Comment: @Bergi - Right, it's my bad. Still - it outputs an empty function, what is this for, where does it come to play?

Comment: @StevensHaen `Object.getPrototypeOf()` returns the object that an instance is actively inheriting from. The `prototype` property of a function is what `new` instances of that function will inherit from. So, `var t = new Team(); console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(t) === Team.prototype);`. Constructors, being `new Function`s  themselves, inherit from `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @StevensHaen: Uh, that is because `Function.prototype = function(){}` (for dubious reasons, but [it's what the spec says](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4)). That function object does have the expected properties like `call`, `apply`, `bind` etc.

Comment: @StevensHaen: Can you please [edit] your post to only ask specifically about the parts that you don't understand, and that are not answered by [\_\_proto\_\_ VS. prototype in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572)?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You explained it great, got it now. Could you please give me an example of `getPrototypeOf()`?

Answer (score 2):

`Team` is a function, so it inherits all the properties from `Function.prototype`. `Function` is also an  (inherits from) `object`, so it has all the properties from `Object.prototype.` However, `Object.getPrototypeOf` is a "static" method on Object, so it's no inherited.

`Object.getPrototypeOf(Team)` points to the same object as `Function.prototype`. `Team.getPrototypeOf` is undefined.

Comment: People say functons in JS are objects, but they're not, since you cannot check their properties. Their instances are. Why does `Team.getPrototypeOf` result in `undefined` in my console?

Comment: Yes functions are objects. `(function(){}) instanceof Object` outuputs true. And yes, you can check its properties. `var a = function(){};  a.b = 1; console.log(a.b)` outputs 1. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: For example you cannot access a property from the function directly (`function Team (type) {this.type = type;}`. `Team.type()` doesn't work), but an instance of it rather - (`var team = Team();`, `team.type()` works).

Comment: You probably mean `Object.getPrototypeOf(Team) == Function.prototype` with your last sentence

Comment: `Team.prototype !== Function.prototype`. `Team.prototype` is brand new Object, roughly like if you have written `Team.prototype = {}`.

Comment: @Stevens: your code modifies `window`/`global` objects instead of new instance (and breaks on `team` being undefined). You should use `new Team()` instead of just `Team()`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that is I what meant

Comment: @Frax I stand corrected