# someFunction.Prototype.constructor vs someFunction.constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I am aware of the fact that functions in JavaScript lead a dual life first of a function *(as first class thing to create instances from)* and the second one of a normal object.

But I am surprised to see the output of the following console.

```
function A() {
    console.info("A");
}
console.info(A.prototype.constructor === A.constructor); // false
```

I expected it to be true as I was not expecting `constructor` property on the object `A` as it's own property. And hence following the prototypical chain lookup it should have been the same object as `A.prototype.constructor`. Where am I wrong or what piece am I missing?

Comment: The first prototype used in A is Function.prototype because A is constructed from Function. Instances of A (aInstance = new A) will use A.prototype as the first prototype in its prototype chain because aInstance has A as it's constructor. More on prototype can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where am I wrong or what piece am I missing?

That `A` does not inherit from `A.prototype`. `A` is a (constructor) function, and inherits from `Function.prototype`. Do a `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(A))` :-)

From `A.prototype` only `new A` instances do inherit (whose `.constructor` is `A`). See also [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

That is beacuse both are returning different values.

- [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

  > Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's
  >   prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the
  >   function itself, not a string containing the function's name.
- [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Example.3A_Specifying_arguments_with_the_Function_constructor)

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a Function object.

Also if you console above code you will see

`console.info(A.prototype.constructor);` outputs

```
function A() {
    console.info("A");
}
```

`console.info(A.constructor);` outputs

```
function Function() { [native code] } // both are different.
```