# in javascript, why Array.constructor points to Function?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype

I'm currently studying javascript prototype and inheritance and have come up with the following code

```
> Array.constructor === Function;
< true
> Function.constructor === Function;
< true
```

I couldn't get why `Array.constructor` is pointing to `Function` and why `Function.constructor` is pointing to `Function`? What is the reason behind it? Why did the creator of javascript made it the way it is?

Comment: Because `Array` is a function and its constructor is `Function`? `Function` is also a function and its constructor is also `Function`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [someFunction.Prototype.constructor vs someFunction.constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846423/somefunction-prototype-constructor-vs-somefunction-constructor)

Comment: All constructors are functions. This is true in all programming languages, javascript, Java, C++, go etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` is a function — if it weren't, you wouldn't be able to write `new Array()`.

Thus, its constructor property points to `Function`.

You were probably looking for `Array.prototype.constructor`, which is indeed `Array`. `Function.prototype.constructor`, on the other hand, is `Function` as expected.

Properties of a constructor function's `prototype` are those that are inherited by any instances you construct; for example `new Array().constructor === Array.prototype.constructor`.

Static properties like `Array.constructor`, are inherited from `Function.prototype` instead, because constructors are functions and thus instances of `Function`.

```js
console.log(
  Array.prototype.constructor === Array //=> true
)

console.log(
  Function.prototype.constructor === Function //=> true
)
```

Comment: I think it would be good to explain the difference between `Array.constructor` and `Array.prototype.constructor`, as in what they mean and what they're there for.

Comment: Does the above explanation make sense? Feel free to give me other suggestions. I have also added a potential duplicate; this question has been asked before.