# Where the __proto__ is pointing when we change the prototype of the parent object?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Normally when we create a new object using "new" keyword, actually the **__proto__** property of the created object is pointing to the **prototype** property of the parent class. We can test this as below :

```
function myfunc(){};
myfunc.prototype.name="myfunction";
var child= new myfunc();
child.__proto__=== myfunc.prototype  ---> true
```

But let's see what happens when I change the prototype of the parent function:

```
myfunc.prototype={};
child.__proto__=== myfunc.prototype  ---> false
child.name   ------> "myfunction"
```

So if **child.__proto__** isn't pointing to the myfunc.prototype, so where it is pointing in objects chain?  More important if it doesn't point to the myfunc.prototype, then how it has access to the **"name"** property of **myfunc** class?

Comment: The `child` is still referencing the original `prototype` object before it was replaced. Instances don't point back to their constructor's `prototype` property; they refer to the object itself with their own `[[Prototype]]` property (which `__proto__` is a getter/setter of).

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: Ok. The where it is pointing now? There should be an object that the child.__proto__ is pointing now.

Comment: @ Achrome I've read this question millions of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `new` operator to create an Object, a new JavaScript Object will be created and its internal `__proto__` property will be set to the `prototype` of the function.

At this point

```
console.log(myfunc.prototype);
```

is referring to the object

```
{ name: 'myfunction' }
```

So, when you do

```
var child = new myfunc();
```

internally

```
child.__proto__ = myfunc.prototype;
```

is happening. Now, the important thing to understand here is, in JavaScript, **when you use assignment operator, the left hand side name will be just made to refer the result of the right hand side expression**. So, in this case, `child.__proto__` is just another name for the object referred by the name `myfunc.prototype`. Now, both `child.__proto__ === myfunc.prototype` and are referring to `{ name: 'myfunction' }`. That is why `child.__proto__ === myfunc.prototype` is returning `true`.

Now, when you do

```
myfunc.prototype = {};
```

you are making `myfunc.prototype` refer the new object `{}`, but the `child.__proto__` is still referring to the old object `{ name: 'myfunction' }`. That is why `child.__proto__ === myfunc.prototype` returns `false` and `child.name` still says `myfunction`.