# __proto__ and prototype difference

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

From what I know a function should inherit the properties from its `prototype` object, which can be accessed using `.prototype` or `__proto__` property.

```
//my prototype Object
var myObj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

var myFunc = function () {};

// setting function's `prototype` property
myFunc.prototype = myObj;
alert(myFunc.a);
//returns undefined (Why???) I was expecting 1
```

But when I tried the following,

```
//setting function __proto__ property
myFunc.__proto__ = myObj;
//returns 1
alert(myFunc.a);
```

So why does it work when I set `myFunc.__proto__` and not when I set `myFunc.prototype`?

I did refer to [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) but couldn't figure out.

Comment: http://es5.github.io/ knows nothing about `__proto__` at all. Which means it's not a part of the standard and you should never use it.

Comment: No, the prototype of an object (the one with it inherits from) is **not** the `.prototype`. Have you read all answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript? What did you not understand specifically (we're happy to improve them)?

Comment: then what is .prototype used for??

Comment: @Flake: [On constructor functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/1048572)

Comment: so it means that '.prototype' is used as prototype of objects constructed by that function, but it has nothing to do with that function's own prototype

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**`__proto__`**

You can actually access the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of an object with `__proto__`. You can think of `[[Prototype]]` as the actual parent of the current object, in the inheritance hierarchy.

**`prototype`**

This is a special property, when set on a (constructor) function object, used to establish the inheritance chain for instances created from the constructor. For example,

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = {a: 1};
```

Now, when you create a new object of type `Foo`, the newly created object's internal `[[Prototype]]` property will refer the `Foo.prototype` object. You can confirm that like this

```
console.assert((new Foo()).__proto__ === Foo.prototype);
```

---

In your case,

```
myFunc.prototype = myObj;
```

you are creating a `prototype` property on the function object and this will be used only when you are creating new objects with this function (constructor function). You might want to think of it as a template for the new objects. So, when you do `myFunc.a`, JS engine tries to find `a` in `myFunc` and its parents in the prototype chain and it doesn't find it, that is why it returns `undefined`.

But, when you do

```
myFunc.__proto__ = myObj;
```

you are setting the parent of `myFunc`, in the prototype chain, to `myObj`. So, when you do `myFunc.a`, JS engine first tries to find `a` in `myFunc` object itself, and it is not there. So, it tries to find it in its immediate parent, which is `myObj`. That is why it returns `1` in this case.

---

**Note:** You can use the following function to understand the prototype chain better

```
function printPrototypeChain(object) {
    while (object !== null) {
        console.log(object);
        object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object);
    }
}
```

Now, let us print the prototype chain when the object is set as the `prototype` property of the function object.

```
function myFunc() {}
myFunc.prototype = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
printPrototypeChain(myFunc);
```

The output will be

```
[Function: myFunc]
[Function: Empty]
{}
```

None of these objects have `a` defined, so `undefined` is returned. But, in this case,

```
function myFunc() {}
myFunc.__proto__ = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
printPrototypeChain(myFunc);
```

the prototype chain becomes like this

```
[Function: myFunc]
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
{}
```

and `a` is found in `myFunc`'s immediate parent. So, corresponding value `1` is returned.

**Note:** Don't use `__proto__` in your actual code, as it is retained in the latest versions of JavaScript specification just for backward compatibility. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) instead.

Comment: two prototype for a function......dats confusing!!!

Comment: When you do myFunc.prototype = myObj; myObj is available to myFunc instances and not for myFunc it self.
var x = new myFunc(); 
console.log(x.a); //returns 1

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `myFunc`, which is a constructor, with an *instance* of `myFunc`.

If you do something like this:

```
var o = new myFunc();
alert(o.a);
```

It will alert 1 because `o` is an instance of `myFunc`, so its `a` property comes from the `myFunc` prototype.

If you set `__proto__`, you're literally swapping out the Function prototype that `myFunc` was inheriting from before and replacing it with your prototype object.  In fact, after you do that, any methods you can normally use on functions, such as `call`, won't be found on `myFunc` anymore.

```
myFunc.__proto__ = myObj;
myFunc.call(null); // Will throw an error
```

Answer (score 0):

All JS objects have `__proto__` system property. If you try to get the propery `x` value of an object `a`, first of all this property is searched among object `a` properties. If nothing found the property will be searched among `a.__proto__` peroperties. And so on.
That is why `myFunc.a` ruturns `1` in your example.
When you set `myFunc.prototype=myObj` that means that `myObj` will be used in future when you create instances of `myFunc`:

```
var mf = new myFunc();
```

and that doesn't mean that `myFunc` must have `a` protpery itself, as I mentioned above.