# Why don't i get _ _ proto _ _ when i console log in chrome rather i get [[ Prototype ]]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, prototype

i was watching a video of colorcode and when he is doing console.log for an array he is getting **proto** but i am getting [[Prototype]].

[image: Image of the yt video]

-----------------VS----------------

[image]

Comment: I get `<prototype>: Array []` in firefox. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451881/prototype-vs-prototype-what-is-the-difference-mycons-proto-myco https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340608/proto-and-prototype-difference