# How does Javascript prototype linkage and delegation work?

Tags: javascript, prototype, delegation

```
function func() {}

func.prototype.foo = "Var"

console.log(func.foo) // undefined

var foonew = new func() 

console.log(foonew.foo) // Var
```

Why is func.foo unable to lookup the prototype property??

```
function func() {}

func.__proto__.foo = "Var"

console.log(func.foo) // Var

var foonew = new func() 

console.log(foonew.foo) // undefined
```

When using the **proto** reference to the prototype it looks like the behavior is reversed.

Comment: @Vohuman. I am not looking to compare __proto__ and prototype properties. I am trying to understand why a particular lookup is not working.

Comment: The question and accepted answer that @Vohuman linked clearly explains why your first lookup is failing. It also explains implicitly why you should not modify `__proto__`, which explains the second lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the [[Prototype]] with the `prototype`.

The [[Prototype]], also known as `__proto__`, is an internal property which determines from which object the current object should inherit from.

The `prototype` is a property of constructors which determines the [[Prototype]] of newly created instances.

This is fully explained in [`__proto__` VS. `prototype` in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1529630).

You can achieve both behaviors by setting the [[Prototype]] of the constructor to its `prototype`. You can use `setPrototypeOf` (or `__proto__`) for that:

```
function func() {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(func, func.prototype);
func.prototype.foo = "Var";

func.foo;       // "Var"
new func().foo; // "Var"
```

I don't recommend it, though.