# prototype property is absent in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript

I've just opened Chrome Dev Tools and typed this code:

```
function Car() { 
    this.value = 10; 
}
var cc = new Car();
```

But when I typed this code:

```
cc.prototype
```

I got `undefined`. Why?
As I know 'cc' object must have the same prototype as Car constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_proto\_\_ VS. prototype in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: And why would you access the prototype of the new instance, are you sure you don't want `Car.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cc.__proto__` to get the prototype object.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959753/4466618 for the difference.

Comment: Instead, flag as dupe please.

Comment: Well it is not exactly duplicate, as op did not ask what is the difference between both but why .prototype is undefined.

Comment: The linked question exactly explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype is inside the `cc.__proto__` attribute.

The browser (JS engine) place it there.

The new function looks something like:

```
function new() {
   var newObj = {},
   fn = this,
   args = arguments,
   fnReturn;

   // Setup the internal prototype reference
   newObj.__proto__ = fn.prototype;

   // Run the constructor with the passed arguments
   fnReturn = fn.apply(newObj, args);

   if (typeof fnReturn === 'object') {
       return fnReturn;
   }

   return newObj;
}
```

This line is the relevant line for you:

```
newObj.__proto__ = fn.prototype;
```

#### The Object.prototype

The `Car.prototype` is the definition of all the methods and properties of the Car object. The `cc` instance store it inits `__proto__`