# Different ways of extending class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, eventemitter

I'm reading [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/) on extending the EventEmitter class in node and there's a small part that I don't understand:

```
Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

I've looked up several articles on how this is supposed to work but really don't understand it. I know that alternatively, I could also use `util.inherits` but I'm trying to understand what happens in the line above.

I'd also like to know if doing this would have the same result as using `__proto__`:

```
Door.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
//or
Door.prototype = new EventEmitter(); // I know this also calls constructor
```

So, what is the difference about these three methods, and how does `__proto__` work?

**EDIT:**

So I looked at the links that were posted. I understand that prototype is basically used to build `__proto__` which is then used in the lookup chain to resolve methods. The article I linked to also says that this line copies all the EventEmitter properties to the door object:

```
Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
```

Now my question, which might not have been clear earlier is: if the point of the line above, is copying the properties of the EventEmitter to the door object, I think the same could be achieved by doing:

```
Door.prototype = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: This question might also be helpful (has link to a nice article) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This is all about what objects have access to and why.

We need to understand `__proto__` vs prototype.
I will refer you to this question and answer to help you understand the two.
[__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

The line of code you are looking at is a constructor that is inheriting from the EventEmitter prototype. This creates a chain like system to include methods from multiple constructor functions.

```
Door.prototype.open = function(){ ... open something... };
Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;
var myDoor = new Door;
```

The object myDoor will have the method `open` and all methods from the EventEmitter prototype.

Comment: So if I undertand correctly, using `__proto__` we can change `Door.prototype` after it has been intiated. But couldn't the same thing be achieved by using `Door.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);`?