# Prototypes and usage Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, new-operator

I have a chunk of code below:

```
function Foo(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Foo.prototype.myName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

function Bar(name, label){
  Foo.call(this, name);
  this.label = label;

}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

Bar.prototype.myLabel = function(){
   return this.label;
}

var a = new Bar("a" , "obj a");

a.myName();
a.myLabel();
```

Okay, now as per my understanding

1. It creates a function `Foo` which sets the name
2. It creates a function `myName` on the linked prototype Object of Foo.
3. It creates a function `Bar` which just sets the label and uses the function Foo's functionality to set the name instead of doing it itself.
4. Then the prototype linkage is established between Foo and Bar. So I assume that there are two separate prototype objects linked to one another for Foo and Bar respectively.
5. Now Bar's prototype object is having a function `myLabel` inside it.
6. The call to new Bar creates a new object `a` and links it's prototype object to Bar's prototype.

So **takeways** are :

- Foo's prototype contains one get function - `myName`
- Foo itself just sets a property- name
- Bar's prototype is having one get function - `myLabel`
- Bar itself is just setting a property - mylabel
- The object `a's` prototype is linked to `Bar's prototype` which in itself is linked to `Foo's prototype`. So in total there are three prototype objects.

Is this flow of thinking correct ?  Please rectify or add something to enlighten the discussion. I am fairly new to the language and it's nuances and hardly the use cases/practical examples of prototype.

Comment: *"So in total there are three prototype objects."* - Not quite right. The object `a`'s prototype is the same object referenced by the `Bar.prototype` property. The `Bar.prototype` property is *not* the `Bar` object's prototype, it is the object that will become the prototype of any objects created via `new Bar()`. (`Bar`, being a function, is also an object that has its own prototype not at all related to what `Bar.prototype` refers to.)

Comment: Ok. So Bar.prototype (or any object's protype after  new call) and Foo.prototype are again referencing to the same prototype object...is that correct ?

Comment: No, `Bar.prototype` and `Foo.prototype` reference different objects. (Sorry, but explaining this in depth is beyond what I can do in a comment, and I don't have time to write up a thorough answer.)

Comment: Understood that there are in total 2 prototype objects. One of Foo and other of any object created via new call and these are linked to each other.

Comment: Kind of. There are a couple of other prototypes associated with the functions as objects, but they're not relevant here. I'd suggest reading the following question and some of its linked duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript - there are pictures that help show the linkages.

Comment: Goes a great deal in giving a nice view of prototypes and chains. Pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to enumerate `Foo.prototype`:

```
Foo.prototype = { constructor: Foo, myName: function() { return this.name}};
```

Then `Bar` calls `Foo` to apply 'name' to the the instance of Bar being constructed, rather than doing it itself, before setting its second parameter as a new `Bar` object property.

But `Bar.prototype` is set to `{}` protypically inheriting from `Foo.prototype`. So for example, `Bar.prototype.constructor == Foo;  // true`

`Bar.prototype` is assigned a local own property method `myLabel`, inheritable by `Bar` objects but not by `Foo` objects.

So points 1,2,3 are correct.

Point 4 is incorrect. There is a prototypical inheritance established such that `Bar.prototype` inherits from `Foo.prototype`. It is not mutual and is a one way inheritance: JavaScript does not support any kind of bi-directional prototypical inheritance.

Points 5 and 6 are correct.