# Why does Babel use setPrototypeOf for inheritance when it already does Object.create(superClass.prototype)?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Posting the following code into the [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=class%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test2%20extends%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%7D)

```
class Test {

}

class Test2 extends Test {

}
```

you get this `inherits` function

```
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
  if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
    throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
  }
  subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: subClass,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
  if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}
```

It looked fine to me until I realized it was doing both `Object.create` on the prototype **and** a `setPrototypeOf` call. I wasn't that familiar with `setPrototypeOf` so I went to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) where it says:

> If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

Which is confusing to me since they use both. Why is this the case?

Should the line instead be

```
if (superClass && !superClass.prototype)
```

for when the prototype is unset, but it still has a `__proto__`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setPrototypeOf` does set the [[prototype]] of `subClass` from its original value `Function.prototype` to `superClass`, to let it inherit static properties from it.

`Object.create` cannot be used here (like it is for the `.prototype` object), as it does not allow to create functions. The constructor of a class has to be a function though, obviously; and the only way to do that is to create functions using standard expressions/declarations and then change its prototype afterwards.

Comment: Hmmm this is a bit confusing to me. Could you create a code example of the shortcomings of `Object.create()`? From what I read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), it will inherit static methods since those are just methods defined on the prototype of the original class right?

Comment: @AR7: Static methods are defined on the constructor function object of the class, not the `.prototype` object. We are talking about the constructors inheriting from each other here, not the prototype chain of instances.

Comment: Oh so by static you meant [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). So `Object.create` does let you inherit the prototype methods, but not methods defined using the `static` keyword, correct? Although I'm curious...why are static methods stored on the `__proto__` object instead of the prototype?

Comment: Well you can do `Object.create(superClass)`, but that creates an object (as the method name says) not the `subClass` function. Static methods are not stored on any `__proto__`, they're stored on the constructor itself. They are not stored on the `.prototype` because they are not supposed to be inherited by instances.

Comment: "They are not stored on the .prototype because they are not supposed to be inherited by instances." This confused me a bit more. How is this different from "The setPrototypeOf does set the [[prototype]] of subClass from it's original value Function.prototype to superClass, to let it inherit static properties from it." I thought the whole point was to inherit the static methods?

Comment: The [[prototype]] from which properties are inherited is a different thing than the `.prototype` property of constructors. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572

Comment: @AR7 [Here's an example showing how static methods work.](https://jsfiddle.net/dk35aasr/) Essentially, you can only access them by referencing the "class" itself, not through any instances of that class. That's why you don't want them on the prototype.