# When and why should I use Object.setPrototypeOf on the .prototype property of the class instead of the class itself?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I've been getting up to speed on some of the newer features of JavaScript and have been reading about Object.setPrototypeOf(). I ran across this bit of code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which deals with inheriting from regular objects. But I'm confused at how they use Object.setPrototypeOf() here. I expected them to write

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog, Animal)
```

as opposed to what the do below. Why do they write it this way?

```js
var Animal = {
  speak() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
  }
};

class Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// If you do not do this you will get a TypeError when you invoke speak
Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog.prototype, Animal);

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie makes a noise.
```

Comment: Notice that `Dog` is a constructor function while `Animal` is an object (like `Dog.prototype` is an object).

Comment: Yes, that did contribute to some confusion. I was thinking of Animal as a constructor...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Babel use setPrototypeOf for inheritance when it already does Object.create(superClass.prototype)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926910/why-does-babel-use-setprototypeof-for-inheritance-when-it-already-does-object-cr)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for calling `Object.setPrototypeOf` is to make sure that any objects created by the `Dog` constructor will get the `Animal` object in their prototype chain. It would be wrong to set a prototype of the constructor itself (not to be confused with the constructor's `prototype` property which really is a misnomer), since the constructor has no place in `d`'s prototype chain.

A created `Dog` object does not get `Dog` in its prototype chain, but `Dog.prototype`. `Dog` is *just* the vehicle by which objects are created, it is not supposed itself to become part of the prototype chain.

You *could* instead do this in the `Dog` constructor:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Animal)
```

That makes the length of the prototype chain one step shorter, but the downside is that now `d instanceof Dog` will no longer be true. It will only be an `Animal`. This is a pity, and it explains why it is good to keep the original `Dog.prototype` object, while setting *its* prototype to `Animal`, so that now `d` is both a `Dog` and an `Animal`.

Read about this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/5459839). I would promote [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880438/5459839) to that Q&A.

Comment: *It would be wrong to set a prototype of the constructor itself*. This confuses me because if I change `Dog` to be a constructor function instead of a class then this works: `function Dog() { this.name = name; } Dog.prototype = Animal;` What's different? Aren't I setting a prototype on the constructor itself?

Comment: Thanks for these examples. It took a couple re-reads, but makes sense now. My confusion stemmed from misunderstanding the purpose of Object.setPrototypeOf(). I'm used to the old way of JS class inheritance, where you'd assign to the prototype property of the constructor, e.g. Dog.prototype = new Animal(). So I imagined Object.setPrototypeOf() as shorthand for that (of course, here Animal is not a constructor at all). It's now apparent that Object.setPrototypeOf needs to be applied to instances of Dog, or better yet (as you note) further up the Dog instance prototype chain.

Comment: Indeed, the way the word `prototype` is used in the language is confusing: `setPrototypeOf` relates more to `__proto__` then to `prototype`. The latter could better have been named differently, although I cannot think of a short name. Something like `prototypeForObjectsCreatedByThisConstructor`, but that is maybe a tad too verbose ;-) So when we use the word prototype in an English sentence we most often refer to what `__proto__` is, not `prototype`.

Comment: I shared Frank's confusion. Trincot's own answer to a previous question was helpful to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work/42880438#42880438. You want to get Animal on the prototype chain of Dog instances, which Dog.prototype = Animal does. Object.setPrototypeOf() is not shorthand for this, which was the source of my confusion.

Comment: Right: `Object.setPrototypeOf(a, b)` corresponds to (the discouraged) `a.__proto__ = b`, and has nothing to do with the `prototype` property.

Answer (score 3):

1)   Animal is an Object literal
2)   Object literal doesn't have prototype property
3)   the syntax is

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(targetObj, sourceObj);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog.prototype,Animal);
```

4) By doing this we are **inheriting** the properties of 
object literal ( **Animal**) to another literal or constructor(**Dog**)

5) here the **Dog** 's **prototype** is being set from **Animal**.
    this method (**Object.setPrototypOf()**) sets a reference to **Animal**'s  methods to **Dog**'s **prototype**

Answer (score 1):

We can do the same using `{__proto__:...}`:

```js
var Animal = {
   speak() {
     console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
   }
};

var Dog={
  __proto__: Animal
}

Dog.name='Mitzie'
Dog.speak(); // Mitzie makes a noise.
```

The `{__proto__: Animal}` is a way of defining `prototype chain`. Here, this is `{__proto__: {speak:function(){...}}` as defined in Animal.

To understand this let's see the chain in steps. When we did `Dog.speak()` js can't find function `speak` inside Dog. So it goes up the chain once and finds `speak` inside Animal. As expected this outputs "Mitzie makes a noise.".

Conceptually, `Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog.prototype, Animal)` is the same as `Dog.prototype.__proto__=Animal`. We call this setting `Dog.prototype.[[Prototype]]` to Animal. The `[[Prototype]]` is a link pointing to an object one step up the chain.

```js
var Animal=function() {}
Animal.prototype.speak=function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
}

var Dog=function(name) {
    this.name=name
}

// set up prototype chain
Dog.prototype.__proto__=Animal.prototype

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie makes a noise.
```

Here is your example replaced with using `__proto__` to define the prototype chain.

```js
var Animal = {
   speak() {
     console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
   }
};

class Dog {
   constructor(name) {
   this.name = name;
  }
}

//Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog.prototype, Animal);// If you do not do this you will get a TypeError when you invoke speak
Dog.prototype.__proto__=Animal

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie makes a noise.
```

Lastly, you could just use `class extends..`.

```js
var Animal = class {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name=name
  }
   speak() {
     console.log(this.name + ' makes a noise.');
   }
};

class Dog extends Animal {
   constructor(name) {
     super(name)
  }
}

var d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // Mitzie makes a noise.
```

As you can see this approach is the simplest so recommended ;)