# Weird behavior of constructor instance for prototype property

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Refer to the given example:

**Code:**

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}
var john = new Person("John");
console.log(Person.prototype);//Object{}   
console.log(john.prototype);  //undefined
```

Person is a function so its prototype would be derived from object so its understandable that it gives an Object in return (which further has Constructor & *proto*) as its properties.

Coming to second console statement. As, john is an instance of Person, therefore it must have the same prototype as Person has. Means, I should have got an **object in return**. How am I getting **undefined**? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class has a prototype, an instance of a class doesn't have a prototype.

The class has to make new instances, so it has a prototype in it. `john` does not have to instantiate new instances, so there is no reason for him to have a prototype.

If you really **must** have a prototype in the instance of the class, you can do this (assuming the function doesn't change name):

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.prototype=Person.prototype;
}
```

*Keep in mind, it's more of a quick hack than a solution, who knows when it will prove inconvenient.*

Answer (score 1):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript?rq=1) will help you.

"Instances" doesn't have prototypes, they're linked to them via internal `[[Prototype]]`, which is not accessible. Also there is a property named `__proto__` which is non standard (not reliable), but points to prototype.