# Objects returned from constructor do not have a prototype

Tags: javascript

I came across this passage in the wonderful book *Eloquent JavaScript*:

> Constructors (in fact, all functions) automatically get a property
>   named prototype, which by default holds a plain, empty object that
>   derives from Object.prototype. Every instance created with this
>   constructor will have this object as its prototype.

So I thought I'll test it.

```
function Person () {}

person = new Person()

console.log(Person.prototype) // Object {}
console.log(person.prototype) // undefined ???? :O
```

The first `console.log` makes sense, but why does the second one show `undefined`?

Comment: The prototype cannot be accessed using `prototype` property unless it is explicitly defined. You can see inherited prototype properties using `__proto__` property.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/5647260

Comment: @Tushar Thanks! Please add that as an answer and I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: @AndrewLi OMG that looks like dense stuff! But thanks, I'll go through it. :-)

Comment: There might be some confusion about terminology here. The *prototype of an object* is something that is used to resolve the members of an object. Where it is stored and whether it is accessible as a property of the object unto itself is an implementation detail. The *`prototype` property of a constructor* is just that; a property of the constructor function named `prototype`. If you set, this, it will *become* the prototype of all instances created from this constructor.

Comment: One of the comment in link shared by @AndrewLi says `So prototype is not available on the instances themselves (or other objects), but only on the constructor functions` I think this says it all. `person.constructor.prototype == Person.prototype`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Great highlight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Object.getPrototypeOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get the prototype of specified object

```js
function Person() {}
person = new Person();
console.log(Person.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(person));
```

Comment: *Current standards provide an equivalent Object.getPrototypeOf(O) method, though de facto standard `__proto__` is quicker.* - from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/5647260).

Comment: I think I'll always use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to make things simpler. Still, it's good to know the details.