# Extend an object with an extension in JS

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

```
function extend( obj, extension ){
  for ( var key in extension ){
    obj[key] = extension[key];
  }
}
```

Context: Used in the Observer Pattern  https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript

For example:

```
// Extend the controlling checkbox with the Subject class
extend( controlCheckbox, new Subject() );
```

With

```
function Subject(){
  this.observers = new ObserverList();
}

Subject.prototype.addObserver = function( observer ){
  this.observers.add( observer );
};

Subject.prototype.removeObserver = function( observer ){
  this.observers.removeAt( this.observers.indexOf( observer, 0 ) );
};

Subject.prototype.notify = function( context ){
  var observerCount = this.observers.count();
  for(var i=0; i < observerCount; i++){
    this.observers.get(i).update( context );
  }
};
```

**What I think is going on:** The for loop goes through the `Subject`'s  properties that I added before and then adds it to the Observer-object.

**What I don't understand:** How come it only adds those properties that I added before (i.e. observers, addObserver, removeObserver, notify) but not **ALL** properties of the extension object?

For example when I print out the extension object I can see that the `constructor`- or the `__proto__` property is **NOT** added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `extend` is making `obj` inherit the properties and methods of `extension`.

So, in this case, `controlCheckbox`, is inheriting the properties and methods of `Subject`.

You will get all the properties and methods from `Subject` but `__proto__` is not a property or method - it is the actual object that is used in the lookup chain to resolve methods, etc. There is a good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) which discusses `__proto__`

**UPDATE**
Indeed, **proto** is a property - but it is a special kind of property. [From here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342818(v=vs.94).aspx):

> Contains a reference to the internal prototype of the specified object.
>
> An object can have only a single prototype (not including inherited prototypes in the prototype chain)...

So in the chain, you will have a `__proto__` for `controlCheckbox` and one of the properties of its `__proto__` **should be** the `__proto__` from `Subjects` containing all its properties and methods.

**UPDATE 2**
When using `for (propName in obj)` loops, the **proto** property is not added because it is not enumerable. Only enumerable inherited properties are returned. You can search on `Enumerable` and `propertyIsEnumerable()` to get more information.