# confusion over "Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype" returning "true"

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

I have always thought that functions in javascript are objects and `Function.__proto__` is equal to `Object.prototype`. But when I have entered the following code in chrome console, the outputs are

```
> Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype;
> false
> Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype;
> true
```

I'm very confused right now. Does function inherit from object? or it is the other way around?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript#9959753

Comment: You seem to be assuming all objects have `__proto__` set to `Object.prototype`. That's not the case.

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing me to potential answers. I have seen the post by 0x90 but in the diagram, it does indicate "Function.__proto__ === Object.prototype", which is not what I have got

Comment: @user2357112 if possible, could you please expand on that a little bit more?

Comment: @user2357112 I understand (hopefully my understanding is correct) that all objects will eventually reach "Object" when you following the prototype chain, but they dont have to inherit directly from "Object".

Comment: @TonyStark Virtually zero objects inherit from `Object`. It's `Object.prototype` which they inherit from.

Comment: There is a difference between saying "functions are objects" and "`Object` is a function", because both of those statements are true, but they refer to different things.

Comment: @zzzzBov could you please expand on this a little bit? Because for a beginner like me, the distinction may not be that obvious.

Comment: @TonyStark: Here’s an object: `{}`. It’s not a function. `Object` (the constructor for an object like `{}`) *is* a function, and you can call it (`Object()`).

Comment: If it helps, the correct form of your original checks would be `Function.prototype instanceof Object` and `Object.prototype instanceof Function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is a function (you can use `new Object()`), therefore:

```
Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype // true
```

Likewise, [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is a function (you can use `new Function()`), therefore:

```
Function.__proto__ === Function.prototype // true
```

---

If we go one level deeper, all functions are objects, so therefore:

```
Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype // true
```

Comment: so does it mean, that "Function" is the end of prototype chain, not "Object"?

Comment: @TonyStark: Yes, and `Object.__proto__.__proto__` is `Object.prototype`, so the whole prototype chain is Object → Function.

Comment: No, `Function.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype`. You're just noticing a circular relationship that `Function` possesses.

Comment: lol i'm confused :(

Comment: @TonyStark: I guess this depends which side of the chain you consider the “end”. `Object` is a function. Its prototype is `Function.prototype`, the first prototype on the chain. The prototype of `Function.prototype` is `Object.prototype`, the last prototype on the chain. This means that `Object` is both a function and an object (because all functions are objects), which you can verify with `Object instanceof Function` and `Object instanceof Object`.

Comment: @Ryan By "circular relationship", I was referring to how `Function` inherits from its own prototype.

Comment: I have heard people saying javascript's prototype inheritance is a really smart way of doing business, but man, it sure is hard to learn

Comment: @TonyStark In practice, it's best to ignore the fact that the `__proto__` property exists at all (firstly because it's non-standard, and secondly because it's best practice to never change it except when the object is first created). These particular examples are confusing, because you're placing emphasis on what the constructor functions inherit from, when you should be thinking about what the objects produced by the constructor functions inherit from.