# how to explain Object instanceof Object returns true in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)) === Object.prototype; // true
```

But why they design Object like this?

---

```
function A(){};
A.prototype = A.__proto__ = new A();
A instanceof A;// true
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: Notice that in your example, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(A)) == A.prototype` does *not* hold

Comment: @Bergi you are right, the example just show the first layer,Object's proto chain is deeper....

Answer (score 0):

How else would they have designed it? It follows naturally from the rules "The `Object` constructor is a function", "Every function inherits from `Function.prototype`", "Every function is an object" and "Every object inherits from `Object.prototype`".