# prototypical inheritance javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, proto

Coming from a Java background, Javascript is a new world I'm trying to grasp. 
Im kind of struggeling with how prototypical inheritance exactly works. 
What i got from  [__proto__ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript[1]) and other sources was helpfull but I really want to make sure I grasp this topic. Are the following statements right?

`__proto__`, a property of objects, is an object which represents the prototype of the object. This object can in turn also have an `__proto__` property until the Object object, the end of the chain is reached.

`prototype`is a property on a function object and is an object itself. When an object is instantiated from a function using the `new` keyword, the `__proto__` of that new instance will be the `prototype` property of the constructor function. For instance:

```
let random =  new Array();

console.log(random.__proto__);   //logs the object which is the prototype of random
console.log(Array.prototype);    //logs the same object as random.__proto__

console.log(random.__proto__.__proto__);  // logs the Object prototype object
console.log(Object.prototype);        // logs the same object as random.__proto__.__proto__
```

Also when the objects are tested with each other for equality they are the same object in the following code:

```
console.log(random.__proto__ === Array.prototype);               // logs true
console.log(random.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype );   // logs true
```

Since objects are tested for equality by reference does this mean that there is actually one instance of the `Object.prototype` object and that all objects `__proto__`refer to this instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, all objects constructed from a single constructor function share its single prototype object. That stops being true if the prototype changes after some objects have been constructed: the old objects will continue to reference the old prototype. That would be a strange and probably bad thing to do of course.

Comment: yes, yes and yes ;))

Comment: Yes. You are correct, with one small correction. *"until the Object object, the end of the chain is reached."* Actually, `Object.prototype` is the end of the line.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!

Comment: Nitpicking: the end of the prototype chain can be any object, Object is just the usual one. The real end of the chain is the null value.

Comment: Another thing, the runtime prevents cyclic prototype chains from being possible, even using proxied objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you console.log(typeof(Ojbect)) and console.log(typeof(Array)) you got a "function"
All that isn't a primitive type (undefined, null ...) is an object or "an instance" in JavaScript, means functions inherits from object.