# Difference between normal object variable and prototype variable javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

In javascript whats the difference when i create a variable in object like below 2 ways

```
user.name = 'hello';

user.prototype.name = 'hello';
```

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript

Comment: If you're talking about something like this then `prototype` isn't relevant:
`const user = {}; user.name = 'hello';`. As T.J. explained in his answer, it's only relevant for constructor functions and classes. However, the concept of a prototype in general is relevant for any object - you can see the value of that with `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. It's best explained in a longer article but just be aware that `prototype` is a special property for constructing new objects and it's not the same as the object's own prototype.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, there isn't any, in that in both cases you're creating or modifying a property on an object. But the effect of creating/modifying that property can be significant.

First, note that `user` will only have a property called `prototype` if it's a function* (or if you've created one on another kind of object). I'm going to assume that `user` is a function for the remainder of this answer. And since we're using `user` as a constructor, I'll use `User` instead for the rest of this answer as the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that the names of constructor functions start with an uppercase character.

`User.prototype` is used if you create objects via `new User`. In that case, the object that `User.prototype` refers to will be used as the new object's prototype. That means that if you try to retrieve the value of a property on that new object and the object doesn't have a property with the given name, the JavaScript engine will look at the object's prototype to try to find it.

So adding or modifying a property on `User.prototype` may *seem* to add it to objects you've created via `new User`:

```js
function User() {
}
var u1 = new User();
console.log(u1.name); // undefined
User.prototype.name = "hello";
console.log(u1.name); // "hello"
```

It hasn't actually been added to `u1`, it's just that since `u1` doesn't have its own `name` property, when we look up `name` on it, the property from its prototype is used instead.

To further understand the relationship between a function's `prototype` property and the prototype of an object, see [*`__proto__` VS. prototype in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript).

---

* It needs to be a function created via the `function` or `class` keyword to have a `prototype` property by default; arrow functions, `async` functions, and methods don't have `prototype` by default and cannot be used as constructor functions.

Answer (score 1):

First scenario:

```
user.name = 'hello'
```

if you have created an object like this:

```
var user = { id:'abc'};
```

and then you do user.name = 'hello', will simply add a property to the user object as

```
user{name:'hello',id:'abc'}
```

Second scenario:

```
user.prototype.name = 'hello';
```

if you have created an object using constructor;
eg;

```
function User(id) {
this.id = id;// creating an object which will differ in id;
}
```

now:

```
user.prototype.name ='hello';
```

will initialize any instance of user with the name as hello. We use prototype when we want the instances to have the same property and has only one copy in case of methods.
eg

```
var newUser = new user('id');
now newUser will be -
newUser{id:'id',name:'hello'}
```