# Different ways of inheriting

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've seen that in many cases inheritance in js can be implemented like so

```
function Organism(age) {
    this.age = age;
}

Organism.prototype.growOlder = function(){ this.age = this.age + 1}
var org = new Organism("1000");

function Human(name,age){
     Organism.call(this,age); //this sets up the properties on the human object
     this.name = name;
}

Human.prototype = Object.create(Organism)
Human.prototype.constructor = Human; //sets the constructor
Human.prototype.run = function(){ console.log(this.name + "run")}
```

My question is if someone can explain in detail why `Object.create(Organism)` is necessary and simply doing this

```
Human.prototype = Organism.prototype
```

is not enough.Respectively the prototype chain looks like

**without object.create** : 
`Human.__proto__ -> Organism __proto__-> Object`

**with object.create:**
`Human.__proto__-> IntermediateObject.__proto__ -> Organism.__proto__-> Object`

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: I am aware of the es6 class and inherits syntactic sugar. Im just curious how things work on the lower levels though.

Comment: `Object.create` takes prototype object as an argument. `Organism` is a constructor whose prototype you want to use as a base. So you want `Organism.__proto` not `Organism` itself.

Comment: you're right, thats what i meant in the first place, i just missed the .__proto__ in all the chaos. edited it. But the question still remains, why use Object.create at all

Comment: I guess you also mean `Organism.call(this);`.

Comment: ES 6 classes are not just syntactic sugar. They do things the pattern you mention above cannot do, i.e. correctly extend built-ins.

Comment: `Organism.call(this)` is used to make the properties of `Organism` to be the `own` properties of `Human`, as they should be.

Comment: @dfsq actually you want `Object.create(Organism.prototype)`

Comment: @JaredSmith: for cases like this, though, and for most uses, they are merely syntactic sugar.  They simply offer a more convenient way to set up the prototype chain and constructor, and sometimes obscure the fact that the underlying prototype system is the same as always.

Comment: @ScottSauyet fair enough. I just spend my days writing web components, so I literally live in the space where the difference matters.

Comment: So nice to see core javascript question getting so many upvotes! Even in 2018 when everyone just uses `class` sugar knowing roots is important.

Comment: It seems you are definitely confused about the [difference between `__proto__` and `prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is if someone can explain in detail why Object.create(Organism) is necessary and simply doing this Human.prototype = Organism.prototype is not enough.

You can totally do this, and it will even work.

*However* there is subtle problem. If you assign `Organism.prototype` directly it will cause a nasty side effect when `Organism` will inherit all the methods you create on `Human.prototype`. Not what you want.

For example if you do `Human.prototype = Organism.prototype` then `org` will have `run`, however it should probably not have methods of Human.

Comment: But it sounds more logical that `Human` should inherit even the new methods added at a later point to `Organism`, right?

Comment: @karthikaruna Yes, and it will. But if you add methods to Human, Organism should not receive those new methods from Human.

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis You are welcome. Before `Object.create` people used to use intermediate dummy constructor to avoid direct referencing between child.prototype-parent.prototype. If you want to learn more about possible approaches to inheritance, I suggest you checking excellent book Javascript Patterns (by Stoayn Stefanov). You will lean all the gotchas of all possible implementations.

Comment: thanks > Number.MAX_VALUE //true

Answer (score 1):

`Organism` is not an organism.  It's a constructor function that creates organisms.  The prototype chain should point to an object of the right type.

The reason you shouldn't do the following is more subtle:

```
Human.prototype = new Organism()
```

That's because calling `new Organism` sets properties of the object in a way you may not want.  For instance, it sets `this.age` to `undefined`.  It might also have global effects such as updating a counter, launching the nuclear weapons, stealing your boyfriend, or some such.  When you use `Object.create`, you avoid this issue; it simply sets up the correct prototype chain for your new object.

One note on your technique: by not passing `age` in the `Human` constructor and then passing it along to the `Organism` one, you again end up with `undefined`.  This could be problematic.

### Update

An edit changed `Human.prototype = Organism` to `Human.prototype = Organism.prototype`.  The objection to this is that then any changes to `Human.prototype` updates all organisms.  That's unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I guess OP is asking about why not just doing `Human.prototype = Organism.prototype` :)

Comment: Okay but i am not ( as far as i understand) calling new Organism() and assigning the object created by that constructor to Human.prototype. What i am doing instead is `Human.prototype = Organism.prototype.` which essentially is pointing the prototype of the Human constructor to the prototype of the Organism constructor which has methods like growOlder. I am trying to understand how Object.assign() changes anything instead of introducing an intermediate object in the prototype chain. Thank you for replying

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis: I tried to answer the question as posted and then described a problem with one possible adjustment to it.  Your edit made a different adjustment, and I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware of the es6 class and inherits syntactic sugar. Im just curious how things work on the lower levels though.

So let's start with the modern approach and work our way backwards:

```
class Organism {
  constructor (age) {
    this.age = age
  }

  growOlder () {
    this.age++ 
  }
}

class Human extends Organism {
  constructor (name, age) {
    super(age)

    this.name = name
  }

  run () {
    console.log(`${this.name} run`) 
  }
}
```

would be the ES6 canonical approach to prototypal inheritance. Using Babel and simplifying a few of the type checks that don't apply to properly declared classes, we can see how this transpiles to ES5:

```
function Organism(age) {
  this.age = age
}

Organism.prototype.growOlder = function growOlder() {
  this.age++
}

function Human(name, age) {
  Organism.call(this, age)

  this.name = name
}

Human.prototype = Object.create(Organism.prototype)
Human.prototype.constructor = Organism

if (Object.setPrototypeOf)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(Human, Organism)
else
  Human.__proto__ = Organism

Human.prototype.run = function run() {
  console.log(this.name + " run")
}
```

<sub>Transpiled using es2015-loose for simplicity, otherwise things get a bit more involved in order to make `prototype` methods non-enumerable and other details</sub>

`Human.prototype = Object.create(Organism.prototype)` creates a new empty object with `__proto__` set to `Organism.prototype`, *without invoking the constructor for side-effects*, and sets that as the new `prototype` for `Human`.

It's a more correct approach for prototypal inheritance supported starting in ES5 since ES3 did not have `Object.create()` and so required `Human.prototype = new Organism()`. Unfortunately, this creates an object with the property `age = undefined`, which may cause undesired behavior for edge-cases since that causes `'age' in Human.prototype === true`. Other constructors may have further undesired side-effects.

As such, it is necessary to have `Object.create()` in order to properly transpile ES6 `class` syntax.

Another note is that `Object.setPrototypeOf(Human, Organism)` or `Human.__proto__ = Organism` causes *static* prototypal inheritance, in case `Organism` contains static methods. This is not the case here, but if you were inheriting from `Array` for example, that statement would cause the sub-class to also have the methods `isArray()` and `from()`. The former is preferred over the latter because `__proto__` is an implementation-specific hack targeted to V8 for prototypal inheritance that is not part of the official specification for ECMAScript.