# Inheriting prototype functions in other objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm studying inheritance in javascript and I stumbled upon an issue regarding sharing prototypes functions. Here is my code that works:

```
function basicID(id,firstname,lastname){
    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
}

basicID.prototype = {


    setFirstName:function(firstname){
        this.firstname=firstname;
  },
    setLastName:function(lastname){
        this.lastname=lastname;
  },
    getFirstName:function(){
        return this.firstname;
  },
    getLastName:function(){
        return this.lastname;
  }

};
```

If test this by

```
var empID = new basicID();
empID.setFirstName("Pink Panther");
alert(empID.getFirstName());
```

It works well.

Then I wanted to create a subclass of this basicID using the following..

```
function advancedID(id,firstname,lastname,address,picture,accesscode){

    basicID.call(this,id,firstname,lastname);
    this.address=address;
    this.picture = picture;
    this.accesscode= accesscode;
}

advancedID.prototype = basicID.prototype;
```

Then test this by...

```
var employeeID = new advancedID();
employeeID.setFirstName("Black Panther");
alert(employeeID.getFirstname())
```

And still works! But when i added the prototype functions such as this:

```
advancedID.prototype = {
        setAddress : function(address){
            this.address = address;
        },
        getAddress : function(address){
            return this.address;
        }
}
```

Then I test the advanceID's own function with

```
employeeID.setAddress("Metropolis");
alert(employeeID.getAddress())
```

and it didn't work! I suspect the line

```
advancedID.prototype = basicID.prototype;
```

For the errors. Since It changes the prototype object of that particular object. How can I inherit both functions from the basicID and advancedID at the same time?

Comment: When you do `advancedID.prototype = basicID.prototype;` you're completely replacing the prototype, so it no longer has its own prototype.

Comment: `advancedID.prototype = {…}` doesn't "add" anything. It overwrites.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but what's the point of the statements in the `basicID` constructor? Did you mean `this.firstname = firstname;`?

Comment: It's a constructor type of setting values I supposed. Instead of calling getter functions @Barmar

Comment: `this.firstname;` doesn't do anything, it doesn't set any values.

Comment: I'm sorry there's been a typo, it should be this.firstname = firstname. You're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not getting prototype inheritance well, but first things first:

When you do:

```
advancedID.prototype = {
    setAddress : function(address){
        this.address = address;
    },
    getAddress : function(address){
        return this.address;
    }
}
```

You're replacing the entire prototype of `advancedID` with this object. So `advancedID` and `basicID` no longer share the prototype. `basicID.prototype` is still the original one, but `advancedID`'s changed.

If you want to add properties to the prototype, you should append:

```
advancedID.prototype.getAddress = function() {...}
```

Now you'll see that you keep the previous methods.

However, you'll see that if you do:

```
empID.getAddress();
```

You don't get an error. Your intention was for `advancedID` to inherit from `basicID`, but, in truth, now they both share the prototype. Any change to one, reflects in the other.

The correct way to make a 'class' inherit from another, is:

```
advancedID.prototype = Object.create(basicID.prototype);
```

This causes that:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(advancedID.prototype) === basicID.prototype.
```

If you augmente `basicID`'s prototype, `advancedID` will get the new methods, but the inverse situation won't happen.

Comment: "*This causes that `advancedID.prototype.prototype === basicID.prototype`.*" - [No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572). I think you mean that `Object.getPrototypeOf(advancedID.prototype) === basicID.prototype`.

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but I'm confused with `advancedID.prototype = Object.create(basicID);` you're putting basicID as a parameter for Object.create method. I manage to make it work by calling `advancedID.prototype = Object.create(basicID.prototype);`

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the `prototype` part in `Object.create()`.

Comment: Hi, again thanks for the answer. I just want to ask a semi related question regarding my above code. Where do you think I can use `prototype.constructor` or `constructor` in the conditions similar to my original codes? Maybe another object making or in the concept of inheritance @OscarPaz