# Prototype and __proto__, Which statement is correct?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to understand the prototype based inheritance in JavaScript. I read a lot and googled for hours. Now, I need to connect all those infos and hope that you can help me.

*If the following 3 statements are right:*

- Each **object** in JavaScript has a special internal property that we can access via `.__proto__`.
- All **constructor functions** have an anonymous object property, which we can access via `.protootype`.
- The `__proto__` property of an **instance object** points to the `prototype` object property of its **constructor**.

Let's create the following Constructor function, which creates a  **Dog** object:

```
function Dog(name, color) {
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;

  this.bark = function() {
    return `Bark, bark! My name is ${this.name}`;
  }
}
```

Now let's create an instance of our **Dog** object:

```
let mini = new Dog('mini', 'black');
```

If we now open the Console and return **mini**, the result is this:

[image]

As expected the instance object **mini** has inherited all properties and methods of it's constructor.

But none of those inherited properties and methods are inside its `__proto__` property. It seems rather that they are all inherited directly to the object **mini** itself.

Now let's add a new method to prototype object of our constructor:

```
Dog.prototype.myBread = function() {
  return `My bread is ${this.bread}`;
}
```

If we now return **mini** in the Console, we get this result:

[image]

Again, as expected the new method **myBread** is passed to our object. But this time it's showing inside the `__proto__` of our object **mini**, which references (point to) the **prototype object** property inside our constructor.

*Now from the above simple experiment, I assume the followings:*

1. If a constructor has its own properties and methods, they are not part of its **prototype object**. Those properties and methods sit directly on the constructor object.
2. But if we add properties or methods to `.protoype` of a constructor, they get added to its **prototype object**. To prove it, we cannot access `Dog.myBread();` but we can access `Dog.prototype.myBread();`
3. Properties and methods, that are added to the `.prototype` of our constructor land in to the **prototype object** of the constructor and because the `__proto__` of our instance object references to that **prototype object**, we can access them in our instance object.
4. If a constructor has its own properties and methods, they are not inside its **prototype object**. Those properties and methods sit directly on the object and are passed automatically to all its instances. In such case the `__proto__` and **prototype property** don't play any role and have nothing to do with the inheritance process!

Now, could you help me to see if my assumptions are right or not?
I'm especially curious about the last assumption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_\_proto\_\_ VS. prototype in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: Of you only read as much about the problem as you write, you'd have less doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each object in JavaScript has a special internal property that we can access via `.__proto__`

No. Every JS object has an internal [[prototype]] link, which we can access via `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. `__proto__` is deprecated and not available on *all* objects.

> All constructor functions have an anonymous object property, which we can access via `.protootype`.

Yes, all constructor functions have a `.prototype` property with an object, but I'm not sure why you'd call that "anonymous".

> The [[prototype]] link of an instance object points to the `prototype` object property of its constructor.

Not to the property, but to the object itself. If you would reassign `Constructor.prototype = …`, the [[prototype]] link of the instance wouldn't change. The link is set up with the current value of `Constructor.prototype` when you call `new`, yes.

---

> As expected the instance object mini has inherited all properties and methods of it's constructor.

No, there is no inheritance in your first example. The `bark`, `color` and `name` properties are *owned* by the instance. They do not belong to the constructor, they were just created by the constructor code on the instance.

> 1. If a constructor has its own properties and methods, they are not part of its **prototype object**. Those properties and methods sit directly on the constructor object.

Yes, `.prototype` or `.name` are such properties that sit on the constructor object itself.

(Notice that every constructor, being a function object, also has a [[prototype]] link to `Function.prototype`, but that's not particularly interesting here)

> 2. But if we add properties or methods to `.protoype` of a constructor, they get added to its **prototype object**. To prove it, we cannot access `Dog.myBread();` but we can access `Dog.prototype.myBread();`

This sounds like a truism, so yes.

> 3. Properties and methods, that are added to the `.prototype` of our constructor land in to the **prototype object** of the constructor and because the [[prototype]] of our instance object references that **prototype object**, we can access them in our instance object.

Yes, this is the inheritance.

> 4. If a constructor has its own properties and methods, they are not inside its **prototype object**. Those properties and methods sit directly on the object and are passed automatically to all its instances. In such case the `__proto__` and **prototype property** don't play any role and have nothing to do with the inheritance process!

Yes, own properties have nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful. What about the last 4 assumptions based on my example. Sorry, if the question became too long.

Comment: A property of an object can itself be an object. Isn't it that the .prototype property itself is an object?

Comment: Yes, the `.prototype` property of constructor functions holds an object, the prototype object for that "class".

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Dog.myBread();` you try calling not object instanceOf Dog, you calling just Object(function) Dog, like `static` field in another language