# Can someone clarify the ambiguity of the words prototype and constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototype

As an object-oriented JavaScript novice, I noticed not much emphasis is put on the confusion put on by the ambiguity of the language "prototype" and "constructor" which causes me to wonder if I'm on the right track or misunderstanding the whole concept.

For example, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Displaying_the_constructor_of_an_object) refers to the following function Tree:

```
function Tree(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

as a prototype when there is also a PROPERTY called prototype, as in Object.prototype. The former is the type of a function where as the latter is a property of an object. This is sometimes misleading because when someone says instances of an object inherit features of its prototype, they are actually saying the instances inherit the property called the prototype from the object/function type called prototype (not to mention there are other properties outside of the prototype property like Object.is() or Object.keys() that are NOT inherited!).

Secondly, the word constructor is often loosely used, at least in the eyes of a beginner. For example, when one says the constructor's prototype, do they mean the function Person() of a person1 where person1 is the instance of Person()? Or do they mean person1.constructor? When one says "constructor's prototype", do they mean Object.constructor.prototype or the prototype of the constructor Person()?

Further exacerbating the confusion is that sometimes person1.constructor actually equates to the constructor function Person() when in fact they are two different things. The constructor for person1.constructor is a property of the person1 object whereas the function Person() is a type of function called constructor. If they renamed the type of function called constructor to, say, blueprint, one can easily see the how I mean by the confusion.

Comment: well "prototype" and "constructor" are related concepts but they refer to quite distinct things. A "constructor" is *always* a function, while a "prototype" *can* be a function but almost always is just a regular object.

Comment: And `Tree()` in your sample code is a constructor, not a prototype. That MDN page is simply wrong, but thankfully it's a wiki :)

Comment: I wasn't actually comparing the two. I was comparing between the prototype function vs the prototype property of an object as well as between the constructor function vs the constructor property of an object.

Comment: Like I said, the MDN page was wrong. `Tree()` is *not* a prototype, it's a constructor. I've fixed the page. The "constructor" property is a reference to the constructor function used to instantiate an object.

Comment: "constructor's prototype" means `Tree.prototype`.

Comment: But, constructor's prototype could mean tree1.constructor.prototype as well.  Which ultimately points to the same thing, but are different things.  One is a property of  tree1.  Tree.prototype is a property of Tree.  What I mean is when I point my finger to an apple, they ultimately mean the same thing: "apple". But, one is a finger, the other is an apple, two different things.

Comment: If `tree` was instantiated as `new Tree()`, then `Tree === tree.constructor` and `Tree.prototype === tree.constructor.prototype`; the "constructor" property on the instance points to the constructor function.

Comment: Keep in mind that references to objects (functions included) are all the same sort of thing; two references to the same object are equal to each other.

Comment: All I'm saying is the ambiguity of the language.  Tree, in this case, is a type of function called constructor.  But, there is also a property named constructor, as in tree.constructor.  Their names happen to coincide and they point to the same thing, but are two different things.  JavaScript founders could have named the type of function Tree as "blueprint" or something else. This is the point of contention and what makes understanding OOP confusing

Comment: I suppose, but then again if we know that a function is designed to be used as a constructor, and instances built by that function are to be given a reference *back* to that function, then calling that property something other than "constructor" would be kind-of weird.

Comment: Could you explain whyTree a constructor, but not a prototype?  You said they both can be a function.

Comment: @Kevvv It's a constructor function, the "constructor" of the instances of the class, so it's sensible that the property pointing to it was called `.constructor`. What else could it have been? I don't see any ambiguity.

Comment: Because functions are objects, there's nothing preventing a function object from being used as a prototype object, but that would be fairly exotic.

Comment: @Bergi so when if I say what are the properties of tree's prototype in var tree = new Tree(); am I referring to Tree or Tree.prototype?

Comment: You're referring to `Tree.prototype`.

Comment: @Kevvv There's [two kinds of "prototype"s in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572), and if it's not explicitly spelled out as either *[[prototype]]* (the inheritance one) or *`.prototype`* (the property one) you will have to judge by context. In case of "`tree`'s prototype", that refers to `Object.getPrototypeOf(tree)`, which is the `Tree.prototype` object. (`tree.prototype` doesn't exist, that's simply undefined). And no,  the `Tree` constructor function is never referred to as a prototype.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm talking about, two different things being called the same name

Comment: @Kevvv Yes, but that has nothing to do with constructors or the confusion you stated in this question :-)

Comment: @Bergi so when I say what's the constructor of tree, then should it always means both tree.constructor AND Tree because they point to the same thing and behave the same way?

Comment: "The constructor property returns a reference to the Object constructor function that created the instance object". This sentence is a perfect example of how a constructor property is a separate entity from the constructor function.

Comment: @Kevvv Yes, the `Tree` function is the constructor of `tree` - it was constructed using `new Tree`. It's also accessible as `tree.constructor`. Given that they are the same thing, there's no ambiguity in the words "constructor of tree" :-) Of course, in edge cases they refer to different things, and then - but *only then* - it is important to be precise to distinguish between "the `.constructor` property of the `tree` object" and "the function that was used to construct the `tree` object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate the issue in code.

```js
// Tree is the "constructor".
function Tree(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// Tree.prototype is Tree's "prototype"
// getName method is defined on Tree's prototype
Tree.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name
}

// When you instantiate a new Tree
const treeInstance = new Tree()

// The instance's constructor property references the constructor that
// created it. In this case, Tree.
console.log(treeInstance.constructor === Tree)

// The instance's prototype is Tree.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(treeInstance) === Tree.prototype)

// Here's the fun part. The instance has property "name"
console.log(treeInstance.hasOwnProperty('name') === true)

// But getName is NOT on the instance
console.log(treeInstance.hasOwnProperty('getName') === false)

// That's because getName lives on one of the prototypes.
// In this case, Tree.prototype
console.log(treeInstance.getName === Tree.prototype.getName)
console.log(treeInstance.getName === Object.getPrototypeOf(treeInstance).getName)
```

Prototypal inheritance works by forming chains of objects called "prototypes". If JS cannot find something on an object, it looks for it on the object's prototype (usually, another object). It recursively does this until there's no more, the last one being `Object.prototype`.

The chain for the code above would look like this:

```
Object.prototype <- Tree.prototype <- treeInstance
```

So...

- A "constructor" is the function that initializes your instance. It's always a function. `this` inside a constructor is your instance-to-be.
- A "prototype" is the next "thing" JS asks from when it cannot find something on an instance. This "thing" is usually an object, but it can be anything.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. When "prototype" is used in a sentence like "prototypes are the mechanism by which JavaScript objects inherit features from one another", it's not exactly referring to Tree.prototype, correct?  It is referring to the mechanism of OOP that allows inheritance, not the property that contains methods like hasOwnProperty() or isOwnPropertyOf();

Comment: @Kevvv understand that "OOP" in JavaScript is quite a bit different from OOP in, say, Java, C++, or C#.

Comment: I am strictly talking about OOJS.