# Why can't I refer to the inherited method from JavaScript prototype within method

Tags: javascript, prototype

When I use JavaScript prototype to inherit a object and want to use it's method in the following way:

```js
var Father = {
  name:'Father',
  act:function(){
    console.log('the name is '+this.name);
  }
}
var Son = function(){
   act();
}
Son.__proto__ = Father;
Son();
```

This doesn't work, when Js Engine run `Son()`, it should search `act()` through it's prototype chain.

But why it only works the following way:

```js
var Father = {
  name:'Father',
  act:function(){
    console.log('the name is '+this.name);
  }
}
var Son = {
  name:'Son'
}
Son.__proto__=Father;
Son.act();
```

Comment: How do you expect JS to know about `act()` here: `var Son = function(){ act(); }` ?

Comment: This is nothing to do with inheritance or prototypes. You've tried to use an `act` variable that you have nowhere defined. `Son.act` and `Father.act` are totally different from `act`.

Comment: Try `this.act()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

act is not any property of an object. it is just a variable that points to a function.

When you try to access a property of an object then only Javascript first check if the property exists in that object or not, if it does not then only it search in its prototype until a prototype is null.

Comment: Repeat it again, I now believe the key point is dot function, when use dot between two objects `obj.prep`, the Js engine could find along the prototype chain for prop. that should be what you said.

Comment: That is still the wrong way to look at it, Bill. It simply was not working because `act()` wasn't defined anywhere. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Sorry, Matt.I don't think so. I tried the following and it works:`var Father = {
  name:'Father',
  act:function(){
    console.log('the name is '+this.name);
  }
}
var Son = {
  name:'Son',
  myfunc:function(){
    this.act();
  }
}
Son.__proto__=Father;
//Son.act();
Son.myfunc();`

Comment: the key point is still the `.`: `this.act();` this refer to Son and check the prototype chain to find act()

Comment: Yes of course that works because it's completely different. You're wrapping act in a different function and tying it to 'this'. That's completely different than what you were doing at first.

Comment: @Bill see my updated answer... I really don't think you're understanding how this works.. The reason both `Son.act()` and `Son.myfunc` work is because of inheritence... if you changed it to this, it wouldnt work... `var Father = {name:'Father',act: function() {console.log('the name is '+this.name);}};var Son = function(){myFunc()};Son.__proto__ = Father; Son();` You also changed `Son` from a `function` to an `object`, which matters a ton... That example is not apples to apples in the least bit.

Comment: @Bill see the SECOND snippet in my updated answer.. This shows how making Son an object versus a function is COMPLETELY different!!!! While you may not "think so" - I "know so"...

Answer (score 1):

The long and short of it is the function `act()` does not exist when you are trying to use it.

Just because you want `Son` to inherit from `Father` does not mean JS knows you want to do that.  When you are trying to using `act()` JS has no idea you are wanting to tie `Son` to `Father`... as far as JS is concerned they are completely different functions/objects/etc.. and have absolutely ZERO relation for all JS knows.

Again, you need to use an actual `act` function within the appropriate scope - JS has no clue what your intentions are - how do you expect JS to know which object to pull `act()` from... What if there was a `Mother` object with an `act` method?...

***First Snippet:*** *To resolve this, just build an `act()` function...*

```js
var Father = {
  name:'Father',
  act:function(){
    console.log('the name is '+this.name);
  }
}

function act() {
  return this.name;
}

var Son = function(){
   act();
}

Son.__proto__ = Father;
Son.act();
```

**Second Snippet:** *It's no different than trying:*

```js
var Father = {
  name:'Father',
  act:function(){
    console.log('the name is '+this.name);
  }
}

var Son = function(){
  // using 'act();' here is no different than trying:
  somethingThatDoesntExist();
}

Son.__proto__ = Father;

try   { Son();                      } 
catch { console.log("Oh no error\r\n\r\n"); }

// If you don't assign anything..
// It will work... because of inheritence..
Son = {} // MAKING SON AN OBJECT NOT A FUNCTION
Son.__proto__ = Father;
// If you don't change the name, it will log: 'the name is Father'
Son.name = "Son"; 
console.log("Son as an object {} ... we had to do `Son.name = 'Son'` here");
Son.act();
console.log("");

// But if you change Son to be a function, then inherit, you dont have to 
// change the name... 2 completely different things....
Son = function(){}
Son.__proto__ = Father;
console.log("Son as an function(){} ... we DID NOT have to do `Son.name = 'Son'` here since Son.name will be the name of the function, which is Son");
Son.act();
```

**Third Snippet:** *Or if you did:*

```js
var Father = {
  name: 'Father',
  act: function() {
    console.log('the name is ' + this.name);
  }
}

var Son = function() {
  function act() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

Son.__proto__ = Father;
Son.act();
```

**Fourth Snippet** *Or you can do:*

```js
var Father = { 
  name:'Father', 
  act:function(){ 
    console.log('the name is '+this.name); 
  } 
} 

var Son = { 
  name:'Son'
} 

Son.__proto__ = Father; 

Son.act();
```

**Fifth Snippet** *Or..*

```js
var Father = { 
  name:'Father', 
  act:function(){ 
    console.log('the name is '+this.name); 
  } 
} 

var Son = { 
  anythingYouWantHere: function() {
    console.log("anythingYouWantHere " + this.name);
  }
} 

try {
  Son.act() // YOU WILL GET AN ERROR HERE
} catch {
  console.log("YOU WILL GET AN ERROR HERE");
}

Son.__proto__ = Father; 

Son.act(); // the name is Father
Son.anythingYouWantHere(); // anythingYouWantHere Father

Son.name = "Son";
Son.act(); // the name is Son
Son.anythingYouWantHere(); // anythingYouWantHere Son

Son.act = function() {
  console.log("I have now changed act! the name is " + this.name);
}

Son.act(); // I have now changed act! the name is Son
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my point actually  is "could the inherited function  be called in side a object/function". So `this` is important, the problem then focuses on how to make `this` point to the object itself. This is exact what your example did. Thank you @Matt!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1) Write the `prototype` object of `Son`, not `__proto`. For a discussion of the difference, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript). (TL;DR: `prototype` is the object set as the source from which the object/function inherits. `__proto__` is the resultant prototype chain that is used to look up and resolve references to methods/properties.)

2) Instantiate `Son` with the `new` keyword.

```
var Father = {
  name:'Father',
  act:function(){
    return 'hello';
  }
}
var Son = function(){}
Son.prototype = Father; //<-- prototype, not __proto__
let foo = new Son(); //<-- instantiate with 'new'
foo.act(); //"hello";
```

With your current code:

```
var Son = function(){
   act();
}
```

`act()` expects a function defined locally in the scope of `Son`, not one defined on its prototype tree.

Comment: Elaborating on `__proto__` vs `prototype` will surely help readers. Otherwise this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the answer might not be on the key point. To use prototype and new has no difference with just use __proto__. I now believe the key point is dot function, when use dot between two objects `obj.prep`, the Js engine could find along the prototype chain for `prop`