# Is a function's `__proto__` equal to `Function.prototype`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

Running the following code in Node.js (via [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages)) gives inconsistent results:

```
function F() {}

F.__proto__ == Function.prototype
```

Why does this sometimes result in `true` and sometimes in `false`? Is there a correct answer?

Comment: Noone stops you from using e.g. `Object.setPrototypeOf(F, { something: "else"});`

Comment: For what i undestand the `prototype` object became `__proto__` when the function is executed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9959753/5781499 Take a look here 
```
function F() {}

F.prototype.foo = function(){}

console.log(F.__proto__ === F.prototype);
console.log((new F()).__proto__ === F.prototype)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes"? Please also show an example where it does not. For any unaltered regular `function`, it should be equal.

Comment: @Bergi - "For any unaltered regular function, it should be equal." Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Bergi - "Please also show an example where it does not." See my comment on frogatto's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`function F() {}` [creates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) an *object* called `F` that is `instanceof` [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). This instance object has a prototype link to `Function.prototype` object. This link is not fixed, you can change prototype of an object after it's been created.

```js
function F() {}

console.log('original F:', Object.getPrototypeOf(F) === Function.prototype);

Object.setPrototypeOf(F, {});

console.log('after prototype change:', Object.getPrototypeOf(F) === Function.prototype);
```

Comment: Thanks. The result of running your code here is "true, false", but if I run it [using repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NeedyCoordinatedCompiler), the result is "false, false". Do you know why these results are different?

Comment: @user200783: Yeah, repl.it isn’t reflective of a normal environment here (and they should fix it). Judging by `console.log(new Error().stack)` (and the usual way this occurs), they’re running a script in a new context using the [vm module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), but using the globals from the parent context, when those globals are normally different across contexts. Compare `({}.constructor)("") instanceof String` (false in current repl.it, should be true when using the current context’s `String`).