# Where is __proto__ declared in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

Consider this example:

```js
var a = {}
a.b =5
a.hasOwnProperty("b") // return True
a.hasOwnProperty("__proto__") // returns False
```

If `__proto__` itself isn't declared as object's own property then,

1. where is this `__proto__` property declared ?
2. how is this property referenced while searching through prototype chain, if it itself is not object's own property ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript#:~:text=What's%20the%20difference%20between%20__,methods)%20of%20a%20function%20object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__proto__` property belongs to  `Object.prototype` declared in `prototype` object of `Object` and is not own property of object `a` in your code. That's why it returned false when you did.

```
a.hasOwnProperty("__proto__") // returns False
```

If you do:

```
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("__proto__")) // returns true
```

This returns `true`, because `__proto__` is own property of `Object.prototype`

```js
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("__proto__"))
```

** Part 2:**

The `__proto__` property is a simple accessor property on `Object.prototype` consisting of a `getter` and `setter` function. A property access for `__proto__` that eventually consults `Object.prototype` will find this property, but an access that does not consult `Object.prototype` will not. If some other `__proto__` property is found before `Object.prototype` is consulted, that property will hide the one found on `Object.prototype.`

That's how it finds its way in the prototype chain.

Comment: What about my 2nd question then?