# Why "HTMLDocument==Function.prototype" is false?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In my understanding, `HTMLDocument` is a constructor function, so we have below:

```
HTMLDocument.constructor == Function //true
HTMLDocument.prototype == document.__proto__ //true
HTMLDocument == document.constructor //true
```

But why when it comes to `Function.prototype`, it is false?

```
HTMLDocument.__proto__==Function.prototype // false
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be `true`?

Comment: Because any constructor function equals to Function.prototype, like: `function Foo(){}; Foo.__proto__==Function.prototype //true`.

Comment: @qqwenwenti ... why do you think is there something called a _**prototype chain**_?

Comment: @Peter Seliger   Well, I guess everything in JavaScript is following the prototype chain rule, every object every function ... and every html element.

Comment: @qqwenwenti ... *"I guess everything in JavaScript is following the prototype chain rule"* ... exactly, and *IAmDranged* meanwhile provided a perfect explanation for why you mostly can not expect the direct prototype (link) to be the first best match (within a chain).

Comment: @qqwenwenti ... in consequence of all that the following expressions equals `true` ... `HTMLDocument.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ === Function.prototype` ... but you should also be reminded. The preferred way of retrieving an object's prototype is not the non standard (even deprecated) [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property but, as *IAmDranged* perfectly did demonstrate it, via [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Comment: @Peter Seliger I'm trying.. Just thinking a shorter phrase is gonna be easier for a beginner lol.. anyway I'm trying to fix that. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This is the ouput I get when going down the `HTMLDocument` prototype chain.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(HTMLDocument)
// ƒ Document() { [native code] }
Object.getPrototypeOf(Document)
// ƒ Node() { [native code] }
Object.getPrototypeOf(Node)
// ƒ EventTarget() { [native code] }
Object.getPrototypeOf(EventTarget)
// ƒ () { [native code] }
```

So `Function` actually is in the prototype chain, it is just not the actual direct prototype of `HTMLDocument`.

Comment: Honestly your way down to the prototype chain is stunning!

Answer (score 1):

`document` is the actual object that is created & `HTMLDocument` is used to construct it. You can check it by typing  `document.constructor` in the console, which will show  `HTMLDocuement` in the console. JavaScript uses prototypal inheritance & [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript/41343432#41343432), internal `__proto__` property is used to navigate the prototype inheritance chain.

[HTMLDcoument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) itself is constructed using `Function constructor` as any other object in JavaScript. That is why, the following statement evaluates to `true`.

```
HTMLDocument.constructor == Function // true
```

But `HTMLDocument` is intended to use as a extension for `Document` interface. So that, any `object` of type `HTMLDocument` must have access to all the properties of `Document` interface as well. In order to maintain that, `__proto__` of `HTMLDocuemnt` is internally set to the `Document` object. That's why `HTMLDocument.__proto__` doesn't refer to `Function.prototype`.

```
HTMLDocument.__proto__ == Document // true.
HTMLDocument.__proto__ == Function // false
```

The code snippet above means, `HTMLDocument` object will have access to all the properties from `Document` object via its prototype chain directly, not the `Function` object. And you must already know, that is for obvious reasons.

That left us with,

```
HTMLDocument.prototype == document.__proto__ // true
```

Above statement means, `document` object  will have access to its parent `HTMLDocument's` prototype object, as all instance objects do.

***Here is the total inheritance chain for your convenience:***

```
document (actual object)--> HTMLDocument-->Document-->Node-->EventTarget-->Function
```

[image]