# Why JavaScript construction function default prototype is Object.Prototype instead of Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

When **function object**  is used as constructor then proper prototype chain is maintained as marked in point 1 and point 2.

But as shown in following code new instances prototypes are skipping **Function.prototype** and directly inheriting from **Object.prototype**. Is there specific reason for that?

```js
Function.prototype.extraFun = function(){console.log('funny function')};

function Thing(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Thing.prototype.specs = function(){
    return `name: ${this.name}`;
}

var table = new Thing('wooden table');

table.__proto__ == Thing.prototype //true       [OK]            (1)
Thing.__proto__ == Function.prototype //true    [OK]            (2)  

//it should show follow the above rythm
Function.__proto__ == Object.prototype //false               (A)

//why 
Function.__proto__ == Object.__proto__ //true                (B)

//it should be false
table.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype // true             (3)  

//it should be true because function object is instance of Function NOT Object directly
table.__proto__.__proto__ == Function.prototype //false            (4)
```

But issue is why **point 3** is *true* and **point 4** is *false*. Further more **Point A** and **B** are deviate from normal order unlike **point 1** and **2**

Comment: `table` is not a function (and cannot be called). Why would you expect it to inherit from `Function.prototype`?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> table.__proto__ == Thing.prototype //true       [OK]            (1)
> Thing.__proto__ == Function.prototype //true    [OK]            (2)  
>
> //it should show follow the above rythm
> Function.__proto__ == Object.prototype //false               (A)
>
> //why 
> Function.__proto__ == Object.__proto__ //true                (B)
> ```

Not really. `table` is the odd one out. The rythm goes like this:

```
Thing.__proto__ == Function.prototype //true    [OK]
Function.__proto__ == Function.prototype //true [OK]
Object.__proto__ == Function.prototype //true   [OK]
```

Can you see what these have in common? They're constructor functions.

> ```
> table.__proto__ == Thing.prototype //true       [OK]            (1)
> Thing.__proto__ == Function.prototype //true    [OK]            (2) 
> table.__proto__.__proto__ == Object.prototype // should be false but is true?
> table.__proto__.__proto__ == Function.prototype // should be true but is false?
> ```

No, there is no function object (that would be an instance of `Function`, and inherit from `Function.prototype`) involved in the prototype chain of `table`. You seem to be thinking that `Thing.prototype` and `Thing.__proto__` are the same thing - but [no, they're absolutely not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572).

The inheritance chain simply goes

```
           table.__proto__ == Thing.prototype
 Thing.prototype.__proto__ == Object.prototype
Object.prototype.__proto__ == null
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors (`Thing`, `Function`, `Object`) are functions, so they have `Function.prototype` in their prototype chain.

`Function.prototype` and `Thing.prototype` inherit from `Object.prototype`:

[image]

The lines represent `.__proto__` dependencies (upwards).

See [How does JavaScript prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/572897/5459839), where I also posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880438/5459839).