# Understanding the prototype created from a `new` instance

Tags: javascript

From the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) MDN docs it says:

> The new keyword does the following things:
>
> 1. Creates a blank, plain JavaScript object.
> 2. Adds a property to the new object (`__proto__`) that links to the constructor function's prototype object

How exactly is the prototype defined then? My thought was it would be:

- If it's in a function (not using the `class` keyword), it would lookup to find if there is a `[Constructor].prototype` declared somewhere and use that, and if not it would fallback to...(not sure?). As an example if the constructor is named `Range` it would lookup to see if `Range.prototype` is defined and use that as the prototype.
- If it's in a `class` then it would use every method or property to build the prototype up.

Is that more-or-less a correct understanding, or what might I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter whether the constructor is declared with class syntax or as a `function`, the <constructor.prototype> object will always exist, even if never explicitly referred to. Example:

```js
function FooFn() {}
class FooClass{}

console.log(FooFn.prototype);
console.log(FooClass.prototype);
```

These `.prototype` objects are plain objects which become the internal prototype of instances created with `new`. They also have a `.constructor` property pointing to the constructor (the function / class used to create an instance).

So it's not exactly that

> it would lookup to find if there is a [Constructor].prototype declared somewhere and use that

but rather that such a property always exists on functions and classes, and when an instance is created with `new`, the object inside the `.prototype` property becomes the internal prototype of the instance.

> If it's in a class then it would use every method or property to build the prototype up.

Not exactly - a class is mostly just syntactic sugar for a function. What this does:

```
class Foo {
  method() {
    console.log();
  }
}
```

is almost exactly (but not entirely) the same as

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype = function method() {
  console.log();
}
```

The methods are assigned to the class's `.prototype` object when the class declaration happens, not when an instance is created.

```js
class X {
  xMethod() {
  }
}

console.log(X.prototype);
console.log(X.prototype.hasOwnProperty('xMethod'));
console.log(X.prototype === (new X).__proto__);
```

Comment: @connexo -- for `X.prototype === (new X).__proto__`, it works because `.prototype` is on the class but `.__proto__` is on the instance, correct?

Comment: @David542 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript