# How Prototype works in Object Literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, object-literal

I am new to prototypes.
I have defined an object literal like this

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'Prashant',
    sayHI(){
        console.log("Hi, I am Prashant");
    }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Result in console here!!!:
[image: Result in console here!!!]

After console logging the object
I am getting a property ([[Prototype]]: Object) whose __proto __ property is also referencing to object.prototype.

If obj is an object why it's prototype is also pointing to object.prototype instead of pointing to **null** and why they both have the **same functions**?

Comment: "The __proto__ property of Object.prototype is an accessor property (a getter function and a setter function) that exposes the internal [[Prototype]] (either an object or null ) of the object through which it is accessed." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/5768908